# How should I best emulate and/or avoid enum's in Python?

Tags: python, enums

I've been using a small class to emulate Enums in some Python projects. Is there a better way or does this make the most sense for some situations?

Class code here:

```
class Enum(object):
'''Simple Enum Class
Example Usage:
>>> codes = Enum('FOO BAR BAZ') # codes.BAZ will be 2 and so on ...'''
def __init__(self, names):
    for number, name in enumerate(names.split()):
        setattr(self, name, number)
```

Comment: Agreed. Sorry, I should have found that earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python).

Answer (score 5):

Enums have been proposed for inclusion into the language before, but were rejected (see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0354/), though there are existing packages you could use instead of writing your own implementation:

- enum: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum
- SymbolType (not quite the same as enums, but still useful): http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SymbolType
- [Or just do a search](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=enum&submit=search)

Answer (score 4):

The most common enum case is enumerated values that are part of a State or Strategy design pattern.  The enums are specific states or specific optional strategies to be used.  In this case, they're almost always part and parcel of some class definition

```
class DoTheNeedful( object ):
    ONE_CHOICE = 1
    ANOTHER_CHOICE = 2 
    YET_ANOTHER = 99
    def __init__( self, aSelection ):
        assert aSelection in ( self.ONE_CHOICE, self.ANOTHER_CHOICE, self.YET_ANOTHER )
        self.selection= aSelection
```

Then, in a client of this class.

```
dtn = DoTheNeeful( DoTheNeeful.ONE_CHOICE )
```

Answer (score 3):

What I see more often is this, in top-level module context:

```
FOO_BAR = 'FOO_BAR'
FOO_BAZ = 'FOO_BAZ'
FOO_QUX = 'FOO_QUX'
```

...and later...

```
if something is FOO_BAR: pass # do something here
elif something is FOO_BAZ: pass # do something else
elif something is FOO_QUX: pass # do something else
else: raise Exception('Invalid value for something')
```

Note that the use of `is` rather than `==` is taking a risk here -- it assumes that folks are using `your_module.FOO_BAR` rather than the string `'FOO_BAR'` (which will *normally* be interned such that `is` will match, but that certainly can't be counted on), and so may not be appropriate depending on context.

One advantage of doing it this way is that by looking anywhere a reference to that string is being stored, it's immediately obvious where it came from; `FOO_BAZ` is much less ambiguous than `2`.

Besides that, the other thing that offends my Pythonic sensibilities re the class you propose is the use of `split()`. Why not just pass in a tuple, list or other enumerable to start with?

Answer (score 2):

The builtin way to do enums is:

```
(FOO, BAR, BAZ) = range(3)
```

which works fine for small sets, but has some drawbacks:

- you need to count the number of elements by hand
- you can't skip values
- if you add one name, you also need to update the range number

For a complete enum implementation in python, see:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/67107/

Comment: notably, Python will raise an exception if the range size doesn't match the element count.

Answer (score 1):

I started with something that looks a lot like S.Lott's answer but I only overloaded 'str' and 'eq' (instead of the whole object class) so I could print and compare the enum's value.

```
class enumSeason():
    Spring = 0
    Summer = 1
    Fall = 2
    Winter = 3
    def __init__(self, Type):
        self.value = Type
    def __str__(self):
        if self.value == enumSeason.Spring:
            return 'Spring'
        if self.value == enumSeason.Summer:
            return 'Summer'
        if self.value == enumSeason.Fall:
            return 'Fall'
        if self.value == enumSeason.Winter:
            return 'Winter'
    def __eq__(self,y):
        return self.value==y.value
```

Print(x) will yield the name instead of the value and two values holding Spring will be equal to one another.

```
   >>> x = enumSeason(enumSeason.Spring)
   >>> print(x)
   Spring
   >>> y = enumSeason(enumSeason.Spring)
   >>> x == y
   True
```