# Using classes to keep predefined strings

Tags: python

Is that a good way to define a class like this:

```
class states:
    INACTIVE = 'Inactive'
    ACTIVE = 'Active'
    PENDING = 'Pending'
    BANNED = 'Banned'
```

to keep a list of possible values and then get them as, e.g. `states.INACTIVE`, so when I want to change user's status, I do something like this: `user.status=states.BANNED` and it gets value `'Banned'`. I use it to quickly access these values with IntelliSense in my IDE with ctrl-space and it also makes it safer against typos. Though, I am not sure it's a good approach to create a class for just keeping some strings. How can I organize it a better way or is that a good solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this solution is OK. But maybe I would add those constants to the user class:

```
class User:
    STATUS_INACTIVE = 'Inactive'
    STATUS_ACTIVE = 'Active'
    STATUS_PENDING = 'Pending'
    STATUS_BANNED = 'Banned'

    def __init__(self):
        self.status = User.STATUS_ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want is an [enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196876/is-there-a-better-way-to-get-a-named-series-of-constants-enumeration-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

You could also provide these as module-level variables in a distinct `states` module:

```
# states.py
INACTIVE = 'Inactive'
ACTIVE = 'Active'
PENDING = 'Pending'
BANNED = 'Banned'
```

And then `import states` in your code:

```
# example.py
import states

# ... stuff happens to create user instance
user.status = states.BANNED
```

With this method there is no need to instantiate a class just to pull variables from it.  I have no idea whether or not this is the most efficient route, but it is very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this at number of places. And think it is perfectly ok.