# Loop over all variables in class that acts like enum

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums, python-2.x

I have a class that acts like an enum.
I want to loop over his variables (enum's values)

```
class Demos(object):
    class DemoType(object):
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

        def __repr__(self):
            return self.name

    VARIABLE1 = DemoType("Car")
    VARIABLE2 = DemoType("Bus")
    VARIABLE3 = DemoType("Example")
    VARIABLE4 = DemoType("Example2")
```

I thought about using `Role.__dict__`, or `vars(Role)`, but they contain not only the variables, but also the `RoleType` class and other attributes like `__module__`. `__doc__` and more...

I also want it to be represented like this, mainly because it will add more variables to `DemoType`. variables other than `name`, So please try to find an answer this way.

Comment: If you want to use an enum and you can upgrade to Python 3.4 then that has them in the standard library.

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108523/how-should-i-best-emulate-and-or-avoid-enums-in-python?rq=1 has some good answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I represent an 'enum' in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python)

Comment: Im not sure, because its not a question of how to represent an `enum`, It is about how to iterate over his values

Comment: I think the answer is to use a different way to represent an `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reinvent an enum type, it would be better to use Python's [Enum](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) type (which has also been [backported](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)).  Then your code could look like

```
class Demos(Enum):
    VARIABLE1 = "Car"
    VARIABLE2 = "Bus"
    VARIABLE3 = "Example"
    VARIABLE4 = "Example2"


--> for variable in Demos:
...    print variable
```

Comment: Can you use this method and add more to a variable? Like, doing `VARIABLE1`, and add name `Car`, and a description `"A type of vehicle with 4 wheels"`?

Comment: @Nirock: Yes, the new `Enum` type is very powerful.  Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19330461/208880) for an `AutoEnum` recipe that easily supports docstrings.

Comment: =\, I need more than that. My Enum represents `TF2 Roles`. So its like `Demoman`, `Soldier`, `Scout`, `Medic`. What I need is to add a value of max_players, for each role. Thats why I use this pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542862/how-to-represent-enum-with-functions-in-python

Comment: @Nirock: Why don't you ask a new question, `How do I use Python's new Enum for ...`, list a bunch of the attributes and methods that you need/want, and then someone can help with that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, And its not a duplicate of [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python) at all.
The answer is to create the following `list` by the following `list comprehensive`:

```
variables = [attr for attr in dir(Demos()) if not attr.startswith("__") and not callable(attr)]
print variables
```

I can also create a function to do that for me this way:

```
class Demos(object):
    class DemoType(object):
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

        def __repr__(self):
            return self.name

    @classmethod
    def get_variables(cls):
        return [getattr(cls, attr) for attr in dir(cls) if not callable(getattr(cls, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]

    VARIABLE1 = DemoType("Car")
    VARIABLE2 = DemoType("Bus")
    VARIABLE3 = DemoType("Example")
    VARIABLE4 = DemoType("Example2")


for variable in Demos.get_variables():
    print variable
```

Comment: this should probably be a classmethod instead of an instance method

Comment: `class method` or `static method` for this case?

Comment: `classmethod`, since you will need access to the members of the class, I think

Comment: ok, a little research told me you are right. I will fix it right now.

Comment: @newtover Because nobody but you active in my question, I have to ask you personally if you have any idea to improve the answer?

Comment: For me it's too verbose. I would not use it, but it all depends on the ways you are going to use it.

Comment: You should name the method `__iter__` and it should be a generator. That way you can just iterate over the object rather than having to call a method.

Comment: @kindall `__iter__` is a magic method in the class of the iterated object -> metaclass. but a generator would be ok. @Nirock One can use `cls.__dict__` instead of `dir`.

Comment: @kindall, __iter__ can not be classmethod.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to use a metaclass I guess. Or, you know, instantiate your classes... :-)