# What is the naming convention in Python for variables and functions?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, camelcasing, pascalcasing, snakecasing

Coming from a C# background the naming convention for variables and methods are usually either camelCase or PascalCase:

```cs
// C# example
string thisIsMyVariable = "a"
public void ThisIsMyMethod()
```

In Python, I have seen the above but I have also seen snake_case being used:

```py
# python example
this_is_my_variable = 'a'
def this_is_my_function():
```

Is there a more preferable, definitive coding style for Python?

Answer (score 1140, accepted):

See Python [PEP 8: Function and Variable Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names):

> Function names should be [lowercase, with words separated by underscores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.
>
> [mixedCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MixedCase) is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. [threading.py](https://docs.python.org/library/threading.html)), to retain backwards compatibility.

Comment: PEP = Python Enhancement Proposal.

Comment: How about function argument names (in particular, for keyword arguments)? PEP 8 isn't explicit about them. I assume lowercase with underscores for them too. Or is lowercase _without_ underscores preferred?

Comment: The only problem with using underscores is that you can't select a variable or function name with a double click... you have to select the text manually. It is slightly annoying.

Comment: I threw together a sed command to convert mixedCase (but not CapitalWords) to lower_case_with_underscores in case anyone finds that useful, e.g. to do it the way you like but then release it in the PEP 8 preferred way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607374

Comment: One case for the underscored style is that you can use one-letter-words better. For (a rather silly) example, `findMeAClass` is perhaps uglier than `find_me_a_class`.

Comment: I find that the convention of all-lowercase variable names is not suitable in scientific computing, where one often comes across well-known constants, tensors etc. that are denoted by capital letters.

Comment: note that the guideline says "as necessary to improve readability". So you can also just concatenate without the underscore if it looks better. So: lower_case_with_underscores, could also be, lowercase_with_underscores and utc_from_timestamp could be [utcfromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)

Comment: Standards are there to follow them, not question them. I don't hold people who say "this standard sucks. I'll make my own standard" in very high regard. That being said, the rule: `mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style` makes this whole rule utterly pointless. What kind of standard tells you to "do X... unless you don't" ...?

Comment: @rr PEP8 is a "Style Guide", and describes itself as a Convention, NOT a Standard.  It also clearly explains the reasons for not always following those "rules".

Comment: @andreasdr On the one hand, you're right, but on the other hand every naming convention has the idea of a "default" case convention. So, camelCase would have you capitalize the "e" for Euler's number. At that point you could argue that it's no longer acting as an alphabetical character, and is instead behaving as its own symbol. Which, incidentally, is why such symbols tend to be put in italics or otherwise offset (e.g. the cursive L for Laplace transform).

Comment: This might be slightly off topic because I am concerned with the naming convention for classes, BUT: when people say that the style convention for classes is UpperCase, does that mean this is only true for the definitions but also for class instances?

Comment: I don't see the benefit of following PEP 8, while Javascript, php, swift, java and other languages mostly use camelCase for method. You shouldn't change your coding style for each language, that's stupid. In general, camelCase is the better choice https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/camelcase-vs-underscores-scientific-showdown/

Comment: Not so fast, @TomSawyer! The article linked from the blog found that camel case resulted in more more accuracy, but finding "identifiers written in the camel case
style took 0.42 seconds more time." But training in camel case does make us faster in that style. (See pp. 7-8 of [<the pdf>](http://www.cs.loyola.edu/~binkley/papers/icpc09-clouds.pdf). So camel case is slower over all, but safer when there are look-alike variables-- and this was a very narrow experimental set-up, as the authors point out.

Comment: @alexis I didn't say anything about which one is faster in typing. All i wanted to say is changing coding style for each language is a stupid thing. Especially in the Json era, camelCase is everywhere https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml

Comment: Actually wasn't about typing, it was about spotting the identifiers among other words. But you're right, _changing_ styles is costly no matter which direction you go.

Comment: Why ignore the followup? https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/camelcase-vs-underscores-revisited/

So the first study found that reading camel case takes 13.5% more time while the second one found it takes 20% more time. Camel case should be renamed "snail case"!

Comment: Worth noting, from the same document in a section called "A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds": "However, know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes style guide recommendations just aren't applicable. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best. And don't hesitate to ask!"

Comment: @Yablargo switch to Dvorak and you will find that lower_case_names are much faster to type as the underscore key "_" is on the keyboard's home row.

Comment: What is your recommendation when you want a variable that is a reserved keyword such as type ? typee ttype _type type_

Comment: @thanos.a Use `type_` if it's already reserved. `_type` would be for protected variable names.

Comment: mixedCase is rather standard now, underscore takes too much place

Comment: The "underscore separated words" are called snake_case anyway

Comment: "as necessary"  in practice this means guessing what the author thought was looking nice

Comment: @ParthianShot the beauty of Python is that you can use a cursive `ℇ` for Euler's number or curly 'ℒ'' for lagrangian in your code. Whether that's a good idea, is a different question. Especially the first example removes any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1085):

The [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#316-naming) has the following convention:

> `module_name`, `package_name`, `ClassName`, `method_name`, `ExceptionName`, `function_name`, `GLOBAL_CONSTANT_NAME`, `global_var_name`, `instance_var_name`, `function_parameter_name`, `local_var_name`.

A similar naming scheme should be applied to a `CLASS_CONSTANT_NAME`

Comment: a) I love examples - thanks. b) Unattractive mixture of CamelCase and underscores? But: Being new to Python and its more flexible data model, I bet there's solid thinking behind Google's guide...

Comment: @MatthewCornell mixing is not bad as long as you stick to it. It actually makes readability easier if you know that functions have underscores and classes don't.

Comment: @MatthewCornell I wouldn't assume it has anything to do with python. Go actually enforces arbitrary standards of beauty and will fail to compile if you don't adhere to, for example, their curly brace convention. Essentially, it's a dice roll as to whether someone actually had a careful thought, or just really loved the way they do things.

Comment: Would you consider a constant static attribute a GLOBAL_CONSTANT_NAME ? It's not exactly global as it's in the scope of the class.

Comment: then walks in `property` ... perhaps it's a matter of what the item is pretending to be, rather than what it actually is

Comment: I don't know whether this should be a separate question but one convention not mentioned here is how to name function arguments. I think it fits within the scope of this question so it would be nice if this was also answered here. For example if something takes generic lists what should it be. I think it is not recommended to use for example `list` or `dict` as the name of the function argument since these already exist. What should be used instead? ls, dc?

Comment: Just *why*... **Why**?! Why not C# style, for example? It looks so... weird... everything is `lowercase` + `underscores` regardless access modifier, parameter vs variable and also making them longer if `mixedCase`, for example... I don't like current popular Python name convention... The code is so unreadable with such style and big project...

Comment: What about file and folder naming?

Answer (score 303):

David Goodger (in "Code Like a Pythonista" [here](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html))  describes the PEP 8 recommendations as follows:

- `joined_lower` for functions, methods,
  attributes, variables
- `joined_lower` or `ALL_CAPS` for
  constants
- `StudlyCaps` for classes
- `camelCase` only to conform to
  pre-existing conventions

Comment: +1 visual examples.  Though I couldn't see where PEP8 suggests `joined_lower` for **constants**, only "all capital letters with underscores separating words".  Curious also about the new [enum](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1695250/673991) feature.

Comment: `StudlyCaps for classes` is a great universal rule for classes in almost all languages. Then why are some python built-in classes (such as `datetime.datetime` doesn't follow this convention?

Comment: @PrahladYeri: Unfortunately, `unittest.TestCase.assertEqual` and friends don't follow the snake_case convention, either. The truth is that parts of the Python standard library were developed before the conventions had solidified, and we are now stuck with them.

Comment: CamelCase is confusing because some people say it's "camelCase" (also known as "mixedCase") and some people say it's "CamelCase" (also known as "StudlyCaps"). For example, the PEP mentions "CamelCase" while you mention "camelCase".

Comment: your here-link is dead, maybe it should be replaced by something like https://david.goodger.org/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/

Comment: What if API returns response with camelCase, but your python code converts it to some object with snake_case attributes? Is it OK? IMHO, it should keep case of API response.

Answer (score 57):

As the [Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) admits,

> The naming conventions of Python's
>   library are a bit of a mess, so we'll
>   never get this completely consistent

Note that this refers just to Python's *standard library*. If they can't get *that* consistent, then there hardly is much hope of having a generally-adhered-to convention for *all* Python code, is there?

From that, and the discussion here, I would deduce that it's **not** a horrible sin if one keeps using e.g. Java's or C#'s (clear and well-established) naming conventions for variables and functions when crossing over to Python. Keeping in mind, of course, that it is best to abide with whatever the prevailing style for a codebase / project / team happens to be. As the Python Style Guide points out, *internal consistency* matters most.

<sup>Feel free to dismiss me as a heretic. :-) Like the OP, I'm not a "Pythonista", not yet anyway.</sup>

Answer (score 37):

As mentioned, PEP 8 says to use `lower_case_with_underscores` for variables, methods and functions.

I prefer using `lower_case_with_underscores` for variables and `mixedCase` for methods and functions makes the code more explicit and readable.  Thus following the [Zen of Python's](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) "explicit is better than implicit" and "Readability counts"

Comment: +1  I switch those two (I use mixedCase for variables), but having everything more distinct like that helps make it immediately obvious what you're dealing with, especially since you can pass around functions.

Comment: Though "Readability" is highly subjective. I find methods with underscore more readable.

Comment: Your preference was my initial intuition coming from a lot of years of Java development. I like using _ for variables, but from eyes, it just looks a little funny to me for functions and methods.

Answer (score 34):

There is [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), as other answers show, but PEP 8 is only the styleguide for the standard library, and it's only taken as gospel therein. One of the most frequent deviations of PEP 8 for other pieces of code is the variable naming, specifically for methods. There is no single predominate style, although considering the volume of code that uses mixedCase, if one were to make a strict census one would probably end up with a version of PEP 8 with mixedCase. There is little other deviation from PEP 8 that is quite as common.

Comment: This may have been true in '08 when this was answered, but nowadays almost all major libraries use PEP 8 naming conventions.

Comment: @ThaneBrimhall In 2022, I am kicking everyone's butt who hands me newly written non-PEP 8 conformant code to review.

Answer (score 34):

further to what @JohnTESlade has answered. [Google's python style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Naming#Naming) has some pretty neat recommendations,

**Names to Avoid**

- single character names except for counters or iterators
- dashes (-) in any package/module name
- `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__ names` (reserved by Python)

**Naming Convention**

- "Internal" means internal to a module or protected or private within a class.
- Prepending a single underscore (_) has some support for protecting module variables and functions (not included with import * from). Prepending a double underscore (__) to an instance variable or method effectively serves to make the variable or method private to its class (using name mangling).
- Place related classes and top-level functions together in a module. Unlike Java, there is no need to limit yourself to one class per module.
- Use `CapWords` for class names, but `lower_with_under.py` for module names. Although there are many existing modules named `CapWords.py`, this is now discouraged because it's confusing when the module happens to be named after a class. ("wait -- did I write `import StringIO` or `from StringIO import StringIO`?")

**Guidelines derived from Guido's Recommendations**
[image]

Answer (score 29):

Most python people prefer underscores, but even I am using python since more than 5 years right now, I still do not like them. They just look ugly to me, but maybe that's all the Java in my head.

I simply like CamelCase better since it fits better with the way classes are named, It feels more logical to have `SomeClass.doSomething()` than `SomeClass.do_something()`. If you look around in the global module index in python, you will find both, which is due to the fact that it's a collection of libraries from various sources that grew overtime and not something that was developed by one company like Sun with strict coding rules. I would say the bottom line is: Use whatever you like better, it's just a question of personal taste.

Comment: I'm coming from a Java background, and I find underscores verbose and unattractive, with only the latter being opinion. Naming is in some respects a balance between readability and brevity. Unix goes too far, but its http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language is limited. CamelCase is readable due to the caps, but has no extra chars. 2c

Comment: For me underscores are attractive in functions/methods since I see every underscore as a separator for a virtual (in my head) namespace. That way I can easily know how to name my new functions/methods: `make_xpath_predicate`, `make_xpath_expr`, `make_html_header`, `make_html_footer`

Comment: You don't (typically) call `SomeClass.doSomething()` (static methods are generally rare) you usually call `an_instance.do_something()`

Answer (score 20):

Personally I try to use CamelCase for classes, mixedCase methods and functions. Variables are usually underscore separated (when I can remember). This way I can tell at a glance what exactly I'm calling, rather than everything looking the same.

Comment: Camel case starts with a lowercase letter IIRC like "camelCase".

Comment: I think crystalattice had it right - at least, his usage is consistent with the usage in the PEP8 (CamelCase and mixedCase).

Comment: @UnkwnTech The term for FirstLetterUpper is sometimes called PascalCase

Comment: CamelCase or camelCase ? justWondering.

Comment: @SumitPokhrel it is PascalCase and camelCase, AFAIK.

Answer (score 16):

There is a paper about this: http://www.cs.kent.edu/~jmaletic/papers/ICPC2010-CamelCaseUnderScoreClouds.pdf

TL;DR It says that snake_case is more readable than camelCase. That's why modern languages use (or should use) snake wherever they can.

Comment: Interestingly, it also says, "The results of
this study might not necessarily apply to identifiers
embedded in source code. It is entirely possible that camel-
cased identifiers might act as a better gestalt element when
embedded inside programming constructs."

Comment: I think a lot of the reason behind using snake_case was that many system used to capitalize everything, therefore CamelCase becomes CAMELCASE. Now that is no longer the case. Personally, I like to use snake_case for the internal, low-level, system stuff, and keep mixedCase / CamelCase for the interfaces. I don't know how these people do research, my eye-tracking is definitely the fastest for short CamelCase and mixedCase names.

Answer (score 6):

***Whether or not being in class or out of class***:

A variable and function are **lowercase** as shown below:

```py
name = "John"
```

```py
def display(name):
    print("John")
```

And if they're more than one word, they're separated with **underscore "_"** as shown below:

```py
first_name = "John"
```

```py
def display_first_name(first_name):
    print(first_name)
```

And, if a variable is a constant, it's **uppercase** as shown below:

```py
FIRST_NAME = "John"
```

Answer (score 4):

The coding style is usually part of an organization's internal policy/convention standards, but I think in general, the all_lower_case_underscore_separator style (also called snake_case) is most common in python.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Java's naming conventions when developing in other programming languages as it is consistent and easy to follow. That way I am not continuously struggling over what conventions to use which shouldn't be the hardest part of my project!

Comment: I somewhat agree. If language X is only a small amount of the project, the context switch of how to format text can be a burden. The main hiccup is that libraries will have calls in one style (`library_function(my_arg)`).

Answer (score 1):

Lenin has told... I'm from Java/C# world too. And SQL as well.
Scrutinized myself in attempts to find first sight understandable examples of complex constructions like list in the dictionary of lists where everything is an object.
As for me - camelCase or their variants should become standard for any language. Underscores should be preserved for complex sentences.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, one follow the conventions used in the language's standard library.