# Is this idiom pythonic? (someBool and "True Result" or "False Result")

Tags: coding-style, python

I just came across this idiom in some open-source Python, and I choked on my drink.

Rather than:

```
if isUp:
    return "Up"
else:
    return "Down"
```

or even:

```
return "Up" if isUp else "Down"
```

the code read:

```
return isUp and "Up" or "Down"
```

I can see this is the same result, but is this a typical idiom in Python? If so, is it some performance hack that runs fast? Or is it just a once-off that needs a code review?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "a and b or c" idiom was the canonical way to express the ternary arithmetic if in Python, before [PEP 308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) was written and implemented. This idiom fails the "b" answer is false itself; to support the general case, you could write

```
 return (a and [b] or [c])[0]
```

An alternative way of spelling it was

```
 return (b,c)[not a]
```

which, with the introduction of the bool type, could be rewritten as

```
 return (c,b)[bool(a)]
```

(in case it isn't clear: the conversion to bool, and the not operator, is necessary if a is not known to be bool already)

Today, the conditional expression syntax should be used if the thing must be an expression; else I recommend to use the if statement.

Comment: The alternative syntax does have one difference to the and/or method or ternary operator - both values are always evaluated.  Not a big deal if they are just variables, but if there are function calls (especially with side-effects) in there, it will make a difference.

Answer (score 9):

You should read [Using the and-or trick](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html) (section 4.6.1) of *Dive Into Python* by Mark Pilgrim.  It turns out that the and-or trick has major pitfalls you should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

That code is a big fugly and clever for my tastes, but I suppose there's not anything wrong with it per se.  I think this is really just a case of "make it all fit in one line" syndrome.

I personally would have opted for the first form though.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not.

I had a somehow [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331767) the other day.

if the construct

```
val if cond else alt
```

Was not very welcome ( at least by the SO community ) and the preferred one was:

```
if cond:
    val
else:
    alt
```

You can get your own conclusion. :)

Answer (score -1):

Yikes.  Not readable at all.   For me pythonic means easy to read.

```
return isUp and "Up" or "Down"
```

Sounds something you would do in perl.