# Python inline variable check

Tags: python

I want to do an inline check to see if an object exists or is `None`.

Coming from LUA I'm used to writing `print user and 'logged in' or 'not logged in'`.

However when searching the web, I can't find this method anywhere. Instead people advice you to use `print 'logged in' if user else 'not logged in'`.

Both methods work though, is there a reason why I shouldn't use `print var and 'yes' or 'no'`?

Comment: Because readability counts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880430/how-to-write-inline-if-statement-for-print

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Comment: Readability is exactly the reason why I prefer the first method. Also, could you elaborate why you're posting that question @Sterling Archer? That's one of the reasons I've written this question

Comment: Here, another "readable" version `print(['logged in', 'not logged in'][not user])`

Comment: The conditional expression syntax is always preferable. It was added to avoid common pitfalls with the `and` / `or` syntax ([*The motivating use case was the prevalance of error-prone attempts to achieve the same effect using "and" and "or".*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Thanks, that's what I was looking for. *In my opinion though,* this should be an answer. This question is not a duplicate for I am not asking whether such operator exists and the linked question does not implicitly answer my question.

Comment: @Bas: it was that or closing as primarily opinion based. I think there are other dupes but the `and` and `or` syntax make this hard to search for.

Comment: @Bas: [Is this idiom pythonic? (someBool and "True Result" or "False Result")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/345745) might be a better target, in that context.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Much better indeed. Searching for a similar question did not yield any results, probably because I wasn't using the right search-terms. Thanks again