# Why there are UglyCase method names in Google API Python libraries?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, google-api, pep8

I just wonder why Google is using in API client libraries such UglyCase method names instead of existing_coding_standards? Actually, I am not happy to mess my [PEP8 code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) with something [like this](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_python.html#CreatingRecurring) (GetEditLink() ...wtf? class name?).

Comment: Maybe you should ask them! :)

Comment: Because they like it better, that's the only reason for any details of any coding standard ever.

Comment: FWIW that example `GetEditLink()` violates [Google's own Python styleguide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html), so I'm guessing that because the API exists in many languages and they had to use the most common naming schemes.

Comment: @samplebias: Yes, this style is recommended in their C++ guidelines. It's hideous in either language, but at least it's consistent.

Comment: AFAIK all their API libraries look like that. I really don't like it. Every language has it's own customs and conventions and they ignore it. If they wanted a common style across many languages, they could probably also finish every line of code by `;`.

Comment: See the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, quoting the PEP8 Code:

> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts
>   where that's already the prevailing
>   style (e.g. threading.py), to retain
>   backwards compatibility.

So either that, or they just like it better.