# Python: If statement with exception using os.path.isdir?

Tags: python, scripting, os.path

I am attempting to write a quick piece of code that will check to see if a directory exists, if it does it will print that it does, if it does request permission to overwrite, and if not prompt to make the directory.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def mk_prjDir():
    print "Checking to see if", prjDir, "exists.."
    dirList = os.listdir(prjDir)
    for d in dirList:
        if os.path.isdir(d):
            print (prjDir, "exists!")
        else:
            print (prjDir, "does not exist!")
```

But every time I run it, if the directory isn't there it just dumps with an error. What am I doing wrong?

Update with traceback:

```
 Checking to see if /directory exists..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alpha.py", line 73, in <module>
    mk_prjDir()
  File "alpha.py", line 50, in mk_prjDir
    dirList = os.listdir(prjDir)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/directory'
```

Update #2: ospath was a typo, but the error remains.

I want to try and catch that exception. Should I be using a while == True: and a try/except? If so, what does that look like?

Comment: What's the full traceback? Is `ospath.isdir` a typo or is that in your code?

Comment: Do you have a `import os.path as ospath` statement or is there a typo there with `ospath.isdir()`?

Comment: @JacobColeman Not sure why someone downvoted, but always indent your code properly and include related tracebacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly `prjDir` must be a full path to `prjDir`, i.e "\home\my_direc\", othwerise `os.listdir`  will try to find `prjDir` in the current working directory of the script.

Secondly as `os.listdir` returns only file/directory names not the full path, so to get the full path you can use `os.path.join(prjDir,d)`.

```
import os
def mk_prjDir():
    print "Checking to see if", prjDir, "exists.."
    dirList = os.listdir(prjDir)
    for d in dirList:
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(prjDir,d)):
            print (prjDir, "exists!")
        else:
            print (prjDir, "does not exist!")
mk_prjDir()
```

Update: I think I misunderstood your question if you only want to check whether a directory exists or not then try this:

```
def mk_prjDir():
    print "Checking to see if", prjDir, "exists.."
    if os.path.isdir(prjDir):
        print (prjDir, "exists!")
    else:
        print (prjDir, "does not exist!")
```

Comment: The only thing I am noticing is that it seems that the text isn't being outputted correctly, I get 

`('/directory', 'does not exist!')` as output instead of just
`/directory does not exist!`

Why would that be?

Comment: And I've tried with and without quotes, with and without brackets, etc.

Comment: os.path.isdir() duplicates os.path.exists() exist functionality, exists() unnecessary.

Comment: use just `print prjDir,"exists!"`, print is a statement in py2.x not function.

Comment: @rosipov os.path.exists doesn't differentiate between filenames or directory names, so it's checking first to see if it's even there and then if it's a directory (which is useful because it may catch an error in the filesystem)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary You are my hero :)

Comment: @JacobColeman I think rosipov is correct, `os.path.isdir()`  is enough  in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir(dir)` returns you a list of files found in the directory `dir`. As the error says, this directory does not exists, so, obviously, `listdir` can't list its contents.

Why are you doing this loop? Just use `os.path.isdir` to test if your directory exists.

Comment: I was using the loop because of ignorance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also see [What is the naming convention in Python for variable and function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)

```
def mk_prjDir():
    print "Checking to see if", prjDir, "exists.."
    if os.path.isdir(prjDir):
        print (prjDir, "exists!")
    else:
        print (prjDir, "does not exist!")
```

Comment: Because the /directory does not exist.