# How to get the first value in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
myDict = {  
    'BigMeadow2_U4': (1609.32, 22076.38, 3.98),  
    'MooseRun': (57813.48, 750187.72, 231.25),  
    'Hwy14_2': (991.31, 21536.80, 6.47)  
}
```

How can I get the first value of each item in my dicitionary?

I want in the end a list:

```
myList = [1609.32,57813.48,991.31]
```

Comment: A `dict` is unordered. This means that there is no ordering of the elements in the dictionary - you need to access the values by the keys that they are associated with. So please explain why the elements in `myList` are ordered the way they are (first element of the values associated with keys in sorted order, perhaps?)

Comment: Dict is unordered. There is an Ordered Dict you can use but I forget if it's built in so you might need to import it.

Comment: Just looked it up. Dicts are now guaranteed to be ordered so you only need OrderedDict if you need the extra features. Because of this just iterate the dict.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this way:

```
my_list = [elem[0] for elem in your_dict.values()]
```

Offtop:
I think you shouldn't use camelcase, it isn't python way

UPD:
inspectorG4dget notes, that result won't be same. It's right.  You should use collections.OrderedDict to implement this correctly.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_dict = OrderedDict({'BigMeadow2_U4': (1609.32, 22076.38, 3.98), 'MooseRun': (57813.48, 750187.72, 231.25), 'Hwy14_2': (991.31, 21536.80, 6.47) })
```

Comment: Result won't be the same, always, given that a dictionary is an unordered data structure. Needs a stronger justification for the ordering of the elements of `my_list`

Comment: I can't find a linking saying that *CamcelCase* is not python way. http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles

Comment: they are just different naming styles, and many people just like the CamcelCase more ;P

Comment: Ok, as I now CamelCase isn't good for function names and variables. I googled a little and find this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names

Anyway, it isn't strict rule and I think you shouldn't be worried about that. It was just my notice

Comment: Isn't this one-liner going to iterate the whole dictionary when you only want to peek at one item?

Answer (score 48):

Modern Python 3.x's can use iterator that has less overhead than constructing a `list`.

```
first_value = next(iter(my_dict.values()))
```

Note that if the dictionary is empty you will get `StopIteration` exception and not `None`.

Since Python 3.7+ this is guaranteed to give you the first item.

Comment: As of Python 3.7 dicts are now guaranteed to be ordered by insertion order

Comment: But this is not guaranteed to be the case in the future Python versions or non-CPython interpreters. It applies only for a certain CPython version.

Comment: No. It's a documented feature of Python, so other implementations should do it too if they claim to implement Python>=3.7. So PyPy does implement it  (at least for PyPy 3.7+). So it's guaranteed into the future as much as anything in Python is.

Comment: "Guaranteed into the future" with Python still means that in a few months it'll probably require a new unintuitive joke of a syntax. In order to get the *first* value, get a list, construct an iterator, and call the function "next". Yeah, sure, whatever Python. I'll just spend half my workday googling again and looking forward to working with a real language again.

Comment: @EmanuelP if you have a bad day and want to rant, I suggest posting on Reddit. People here try to be helpful. We cannot fix all the issues in the world, like war, hunger and legacy quirks of programming languages. But we can make the day of some people better.

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

one lines...

```
myList = [myDict [i][0] for i in sorted(myDict.keys()) ]
```

the result:

```
>>> print myList 
[1609.32, 991.31, 57813.48]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = []  
for k,v in myDict.items()  
    myList.append(v[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ordered dictionary, use:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ordered = OrderedDict(
    ('BigMeadow2_U4', (1609.32, 22076.38, 3.98)),  
    ('MooseRun', (57813.48, 750187.72, 231.25)),  
    ('Hwy14_2', (991.31, 21536.80, 6.47)) 
)
first_values = [v[0] for v in ordered.values()]
```

The output order will be exactly as your input order.

Comment: Careful with that: since the [input dictionary is unordered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects), they is no way of knowing how the items will be ordered when the ``OrderedDict`` is created from a regular ``dict``. (see penultimate line in the class's doc)

Comment: @Silmathoron , you are wrong. Read in the docs: [Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the **order that items were inserted**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

Comment: Read my comment again ;)
I'm saying you cannot tell if ``'BigMeadow2_U4'`` will be the first value if you create the ``OrderedDict`` from a plain ``dict`` instead of adding them in the right order.

Comment: oh, yes, in this case you're right, changed it to tuples

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary is not indexed, but it is in some way, ordered. The following would give you the first existing value:

```
list(myDict.values())[0]
```

Answer (score -5):

### Try this.Type the dictionary and the position you want to print in the function

```
d = {'Apple': 1, 'Banana': 9, 'Carrot': 6, 'Baboon': 3, 'Duck': 8, 'Baby': 2}
print(d)
def getDictKeyandValue(dict,n): 
    c=0
    mylist=[]
    for i,j in d.items():
        c+=1
        if c==n:

            mylist=[i,j]
            break
    return mylist   

print(getDictKeyandValue(d,2))
```

Comment: Looks like C!  And not in a good way.

Answer (score -5):

#### for getting first value

print(getDictKeyandValue(d,1))

Comment: This does not make sense without defining `getDictKeyandValue`. If this should be an addition to [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591776/711006), please simply [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46591776/edit).