# How to access an element of a Python dictionary (don't care which one)

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

The dictionary in question is a embedding and I would like to write a function that automatically initializes a numpy array to the correct dimensions. To do that I would like to write something like

`np.zeros(embedding.first().shape)`

which obviously doesn't work.

Obviously I can write

`np.zeros(embedding[list(embedding)[0]].shape)`

however that feels quite unpythonic (and slow), so I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: You might get better answers if you add `numpy` as a tag.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71519312/19960585) SO answer.

Comment: How big is this `dict`?  Getting a list of keys should be straightforward.  The iter/next game will scale better, but I wouldn't discribe it as 'more pythonic' (whatever that means).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could understand your goal is initialization of NumPy array with the same dimensions as your first element is?
If so, `embedding[list(embedding)[0]].shape` is a bit unwieldy as you said yourself, more efficient way would be using `next` and `iter` functions - which does allow you to skip conversion (the part where you need to convert entire keys view into list).

You'd do it as:

```
import numpy as np

# Assuming 'embedding' is your dictionary
first_key = next(iter(embedding))
array_shape = embedding[first_key].shape
zero_array = np.zeros(array_shape)
```

The `next(iter(embedding))` line of code fetches first key from the dictionary iterator.