# Python dict inside list doesn't append

Tags: python, list, dictionary

this is  my code.

```
# Lista de usuarios
UserList = []
UserDic = {}
UserListQuery = UserProfile.objects.all()
print "PRINTING QUERY " + UserListQuery
for User in range(0,len(UserListQuery)):
    UserDic['username'] = UserListQuery[User].user.get_username()
    UserDic['titulo'] = UserListQuery[User].titulo
    UserDic['descripcion'] = UserListQuery[User].descripcion[:60]
    UserList.append(UserDic)

print "PRINTING LIST " + UserList
print "PRINTING LIST 0 " + UserList[0]
```

I want UserList to be a dict list. I mean, if I print UserList[0]['username'], it has to return me the username in the position 0. Well, I've many users. I use append and I'm adding the user to the list. It's not working well, it overwrites the user resulting in a one position list, the last user from UserListQuery.

help?

Comment: as far as i can see in your snippet, there is no error.

Comment: try creating a dictionary in your for loop to append instead of outside

Answer (score 9):

The issue here is, that the same `UserDic` object gets used in each loop, so each time `UserDic['username']` gets overwritten with the new value. To prevent this you must create a new `UserDic` every time. The following should work:

```
# Lista de usuarios
UserList = []
UserListQuery = UserProfile.objects.all()
for User in range(0,len(UserListQuery)):
    UserDic = {}
    UserDic['username'] = UserListQuery[User].user.get_username()
    UserDic['titulo'] = UserListQuery[User].titulo
    UserDic['descripcion'] = UserListQuery[User].descripcion[:60]
    UserList.append(UserDic)

print UserList
```

(Untested code)

Comment: thanks, I've done it before.. And I thought that can use dict has a normal variable.  Solved.

Answer (score 2):

per my comment you should try this

```
user_list = []
user_list_query = user_profile.objects.all()
for user in range(0,len(user_list_query)):
    user_list.append({
        'username': user_list_query[user].user.get_username(),
        'titulo' : user_list_query[user].titulo,
        'descripcion': user_list_query[user].descripcion[:60]
    })

print user_list
```

note i also changed the naming convention of your objects since [python is preferred to use underscores between the names instead of capital letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)

an even better way (more pythonic) to do it would be to remove all the excess stuff and just go with a single line loop

```
user_list_query = user_profile.objects.all()
print [{'username': user_list_query[user].user.get_username(), 'titulo' : user_list_query[user].titulo,'descripcion': user_list_query[user].descripcion[:60]} for user in range(0,len(user_list_query))]
```