# Convert elements in a list using a dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of `values` that match with certain `keys` from a dictionary I created earlier.

```
myDict = {1:'A',2:'B',3:'C'}
myList = ['A','A','A','B','B','A','C','C']
```

How can I create/convert `myList` into something like:

```
myNewList = [1,1,1,2,2,1,3,3]
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Not sure if it matters, I created the dictionary using json in another script, and I am now loading the created dictionary in my current script.

Comment: How have you guaranteed that `myDict`'s values are unique?  If you haven't, what do you intend to do with a dictionary like `{1:'A', 2:'B', 3:'A'}`?  Would you replace each `'A'` in `myList` with a `1` or a `3`... or raise an error of some sort?

Comment: In my case, the values are unique. Not sure if I will come across your scenario anytime soon, but for now I can make this code compile the way I want, which is awesome! Thanks for checking though! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One easy way is to just invert `myDict` and then use that to map the new list:

```
myNewDict = {v: k for k, v in myDict.iteritems()}
myNewList = [myNewDict[x] for x in myList]
```

Also take a look at this for Python naming conventions: [What is the naming convention in Python for variable and function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)

Comment: If `myDict` contains duplicate values, this will result in a mostly-unpredictable `myNewDict` and `MyNewList`.  O.P. hasn't addressed that situation yet... for all we know, unique values are already guaranteed.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase honestly I think OP might have his keys and values flipped. But I think the succinct answer works for this situation unless more details are provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
myDict = {1:'A',2:'B',3:'C'}

myList = ['A','A','A','B','B','A','C','C']

value = [key for i in myList for key, value in myDict.iteritems() if i == value]

print value
```

I recommend you read a bit about the compression list
http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/datastructures.html

Comment: Do you mean [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

Comment: list comprehensions are great but using multiple list comprehensions together makes it hard to read and interpret it for humans. I would break it into two parts and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
myNewList = []
for val in myList:
    for key, value in myDict.iteritems():
        if val == value:
        myNewList.append(key)
```

Comment: If `myDict` contains duplicate values, this will append _all_ matching keys to `myNewList`, in a mostly-unpredictable order.

Comment: add break in the if clause to avoid the duplicates:
`myNewList = []`
`for val in myList:`
`    for key, value in myDict.iteritems():`
`        if val == value:`
`            myNewList.append(key)`
`            break`
`