# How to incorporate variable (or array, etc.) name into name of another thing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to create a variable whose name includes the name `kaiylarScore` for example, but the below code doesn't work.

```
firstName = input("What's your first name? ")
firstName + "Score" = score
```

I want to make it so that if `print(kaiylarScore)` is entered, for example, then if the `score` variable was equal to 7, 7 would be outputted. How can I do this?

Comment: There's pratically never a good reason for this. You should be using a dictionary.

Comment: You should learn how assignment statements work.

Comment: I realised that my example contained spaces. This was accidental, and so I have changed my question. Can I make a variable called `<firstName>Score'?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have `kaiylar - 30/04/1984` variable in Python. The Python variable naming rules are described in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (also see this related thread: [What is the naming convention in Python for variable and function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)).

Instead, look into using a [*dictionary*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
data = {}
firstName = input("What's your first name? ")
data[firstName + " - " + DOB] = score
```

Or, depending on the end goal, you can have first name, DOB and score under separate keys:

```
{
    "first_name": firstName,
    "date_of_birth": DOB,
    "score": score
}
```

Or, to take it further, you may define a, say, `Person` *class* with `first_name`, `date_of_birth` and `score` properties.

Answer (score -1):

As discussed in other answers and comments, you should use a dictionary. But in the case of you think you should create a dynamic variable with respect to Python naming rules, you can use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) built-in function like this:

```
score = 1.2
firstName = input("What's your first name? ")
exec(firstName + "Score" + "= score")
```

Actually `exec` function runs Python statements dynamically. İf `firstName` variable is "Kaiylar" and `score` variable is "1.2" of int, then we pass "KaiylarScore = 1.2" statement to this function.

Regards.

Comment: Please imagine what would happen if the user inputs `import os; os.popen("rm -rf /");`. Rule of thumb: Never use untrusted data in `exec` or `eval` calls!

Comment: In my code, if a user inputs this thing then a `SyntaxError` is raised. That is it.

Comment: You get the SyntaxError because in your test environment you have no variable `score` defined. Run something like `score=5` before the two lines in your answer and it will work.

Comment: Not having a `score` variable defined makes you code snippet above useless, as it would also throw an exception on valid input.