# Replacing an even element with another element

Tags: python, linked-list

I am having trouble with this part with my class assignment. It ask to replace an even element with a 0. I have tried but kept getting error for trying to divide it in anyway. Is there a way to replace even numbers with 0, I might end up adding a user input later on, so have to code where it finds an even number and replace it.

```
def main():  

    list = [7, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9]

    print(sectionC(list))

def sectionC(list):  
    for n, i in list:
        if list == i//2:
            list[n]=0
main()
```

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`[i if i % 2 else 0 for i in l]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Errors You're Facing

- Your function `returns` nothing. If you want the result of the function to be visible and accessible once finished, you have to `return` it, otherwise your function will return `None` by default.

  While it is true that mutable objects like lists are passed
  effectively by reference, so that modifying them inside your function
  modifies them everywhere, it is always a good idea to explicitly `return` a value.
- You should *never* name a variable `list`. `list()` is an inbuilt function in Python, and by declaring a variable with the same name, you lose the ability to call it. Change your variable to something more appropriate - `collection` works, for instance.
- `n, i in list` doesn't work - lists only let you iterate through one element. So `for i in list` will work, where `i` is assigned the value of an element on each iteration.

  If you want to have access to both the index *and* the value of an element in iteration, you need to use `enumerate()` like so: `for index, item in enumerate(collection)`.

  `enumerate()` takes a list and returns a list of *tuples*, where every tuple is of the form `(index of element, corresponding element)` in the original list. It is used primarily to facilitate easy iteration over both index and items using the syntax I just referenced.

### The Right Way To Solve This

Use a list comprehension:

```
collection = [7, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9] # renaming list variable 

print([x if x % 2 != 0 else 0 for x in collection])
```

### The Acceptable Way

This is what you were attempting to do, corrected:

```
def sectionC(collection):  
    for index, item in enumerate(collection): # using better names than n, i
        if item % 2 == 0: # check if element is even
            collection[index] = 0
    return collection
```

Note that the logic here is identical to the list comprehension. This is because list comprehensions actually expand out to something exactly like this - the benefit is one of conciseness and readability, rather than efficiency.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Note that `List` also isn't a good variable name.

Comment: @KevinGuan Why is `List` not a good variable name? Does it override something I'm not aware of?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Well, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/159745/5299236). And sorry, we should also avoid use`l` as a single variable name as [said in PEP8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36784169/5299236) (so I edited my comment).

Answer (score 1):

Another fancy approach:

A number is even when `a&1` is equal to `0`, so is odd when is `a&1` is `1`

```
def sectionC(list):  
    return [a if a&1 else 0 for a in list]
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

You're so close:

```
def sectionC(list):  
    for n, i in list:
        if list == i//2:
            list[n]=0
```

Just add an `enumerate()` so that you have an index, and change your if statement for an actual even/odd check:

```
def sectionC(list):  
    for i,n in enumerate(list):
        if not n%2:
            list[i]=0
```

What `enumerate(list)` is doing:

Creates an iterable object that prints out tuples that look like `(0,7) (1,2)` ... in the case of your list

Thats pretty much all your code was missing, but you had the `i` and `n` values switched around.
`x%2` is the standard check for evenness (it returns 1 for an odd number, 0 for even)

Comment: What does enumerate() do? Overall thanks but kind of worried that it may not be acceptable to use since we have not learn it yet.

Comment: I found when I was learning python that looking at all the functions available (like enumerate) was interesting. Try `dir(__builtins__)`

Answer (score 0):

may be this is what you are looking for:

```
list = [0 if i % 2 == 0 else i for i in list]
```