# Getting the href of <a> tag which is in <li>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

How to get the href of the all the  tag that is under the class `"Subforum"` in the given code?

```
<li class="subforum">
<a href="Link1">Link1 Text</a>
</li>
<li class="subforum">
<a href="Link2">Link2 Text</a>
</li>
<li class="subforum">
<a href="Link3">Link3 Text</a>
</li>
```

I have tried this code but obviously it didn't work.

```
Bs = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text,"lxml")
Class = Bs.findAll('li', {'class': 'subforum"'})
for Sub in Class:
    print(Link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `href` belongs to `a` tag, not `li` tag, use `li.a` to get `a` tag

Document: [Navigating using tag names](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names)

```
import bs4

html = '''<li class="subforum">
 <a href="Link1">Link1 Text</a>
 </li>
 <li class="subforum">
<a href="Link2">Link2 Text</a>
</li>
<li class="subforum">
<a href="Link3">Link3 Text</a>
</li>`<br>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for li in soup.find_all(class_="subforum"):
    print(li.a.get('href'))
```

out:

```
Link1
Link2
Link3
```

Why use `class_`:

It’s very useful to search for a tag that has a certain CSS class, but the name of the CSS attribute, `class`, **is a reserved word in Python.** Using class as a keyword argument will give you a syntax error.As of Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword argument `class_`.

Comment: li.a.get,so basically this is like navigation ?

Comment: @Hashik Donthineni  yes, https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit about this ?"class_" I mean we usually use class for selecting class,right? Yes Please go ahead and close it it worked like charm.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there, you just need to find an `a` element for every `li` you've located:

```
Class = Bs.findAll('li', {'class': 'subforum"'})
for Sub in Class:
    print(Sub.find("a").get('href'))  # or Sub.a.get('href')
```

But, there is an easier way - a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for a in Bs.select("li.subforum a"):
    print(a.get('href'))
```

Here, `li.subforum a` would match all `a` elements under the `li` elements having `subforum` class attribute.

As a side note, in `BeautifulSoup` 4, `findAll()` was renamed to `find_all()`. And, you should follow the [Python general variable naming guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159720/771848).

Comment: OMG both the methods are super cool dude, Thanks a lot :)