# Not able to find a link in a product page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to make a list of the links that are inside a product page.

I have multiple links through which I want to get the links of the product page.

I am just posting the code for a single link.

```
r = requests.get("https://funskoolindia.com/products.php?search=9723100")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for a_tag in soup.find_all('a', class_='product-bg-panel', href=True):
    print('href: ', a_tag['href'])
```

This is what it should print: `https://funskoolindia.com/product_inner_page.php?product_id=1113`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup getting href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745514/getting-the-href-of-a-tag-which-is-in-li)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data are loaded dynamically through Javascript from different URL. One solution is using `selenium` - that executes Javascript and load links that way.

Other solution is using `re` module and parse the data url manually:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://funskoolindia.com/products.php?search=9723100'
data_url = 'https://funskoolindia.com/admin/load_data.php'

data = {'page':'1',
    'sort_val':'new',
    'product_view_val':'grid',
    'show_list':'12',
    'brand_id':'',
    'checkboxKey': re.findall(r'var checkboxKey = "(.*?)";', requests.get(url).text)[0]}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(data_url, data=data).text, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('#list-view .product-bg-panel > a[href]'):
    print('https://funskoolindia.com/' + a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
https://funskoolindia.com/product_inner_page.php?product_id=1113
```

Comment: this work fine ,but now i have to get the details of the product from the extracted urls,i think that will be dynamic too,so what do i do ..is this `re` method will on the extracted links or do i have to work with selenium.?

Comment: @jamesjoyce You can experiment. `selenium` has it's overhead so it's slower than `requests` + `re` method. I suggest to look at Chrome/Firefox developer tools and see from where the page is loading the data - and then use that url with `requests`.

Answer (score 2):

The site is dynamic, thus, you can use `selenium`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://funskoolindia.com/products.php?search=9723100')
results = [*{i.a['href'] for i in soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'product-media light-bg'})}]
```

Output:

```
['product_inner_page.php?product_id=1113']
```

Comment: for dynamically loaded pages I'd almost always say it's worth Scrapy instead

Comment: @AeroBlue You are probably right, however, I do not use Scrapy :) Could you post a solution with Scrapy?

Comment: what should be the path of the driver.i don't see any chrome driver in disk.?..This gives me error

Answer (score 1):

try this : `print('href: ', a_tag.get("href"))`
and add `features="lxml"` to the BeautifulSoup constructor