# Why are some imports capitalised but some aren't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just been following a tutorial about Axios and I noticed that in it, they import it as `axios` but when they import React it's as `React`.
Why are some imports capitalised? is there a technical reason?

Comment: Related: [Capitalization standards in importing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130046/capitalization-standards-in-importing-in-python)

Comment: Both examples you cited are typically default imports. You can name default imports whatever you want, there are no case sensitivity rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a technical reason?

Yes and no.

Both of the ones you've listed are the *default export* of their relevant modules, which means the name you use for them in your code is largely up to you (with a frequent exception in the case of `React`, more below). (It's different if they're *named exports*, more below on that as well). I've seen people use `Axios` instead of `axios`, for instance.

```js
// Valid:

// ESM
import axios from "axios";
// CommonJS
const axios = require("axios");

// Also valid:

// ESM
import Axios from "axios";
// CommonJS
const Axios = require("axios");
```

With `React`, is used to be (and may well still be in some environments) that you needed to call it `React` if you were using JSX, because JSX is compiled to calls to `React.createElement`, and if you've used the name `react` instead, it won't match. (With some modern bundlers and configurations, you don't have to import `React` at all anymore.)

*Named exports* have to be imported with the name that they're exported with (so the names are defined by the module author), like this:

```js
// ESM
import { memo } from "react";
// CommonJS
const { memo } = require("react");
```

although you could rename your local binding if you wanted to with `as` (perhaps to avoid conflicts with something else you're importing):

```js
// ESM
import { memo as reactMemo } from "react";
// CommonJS
const { memo: reactMemo } = require("react");
```

With ESM it's an import of a named export using import renaming syntax. With CommonJS, it's destructuring with destructuring renaming syntax.

Comment: Thanks so the format of `axios` just becomes a convention then as it's upto each developer how they do it and one version just becomes more popular I guess as there isn't a technical reason for it.

Comment: @jobe - Right -- and that would be true for the *default* import of most packages. React and others using JSX are a bit of an exception because of what the JSX is compiled to.