# Cannot yield the right values with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I experience something strange from my point of view

I need to generate alternatively `True` and `False` values like this:

```
False, True, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, ...
```

I need to get one `False`, one `True`, then two `False`, two `True`, then three `False`, three `True`, etc

In my mind, using the `yield` keyword in a function was a good way to achive this:

```
def generateFalseTrueRangesAlternatively(limit):
    limitForChange = 0
    index = 0
    rv = True
    for i in range(0, limit):
        if index == limitForChange:
            rv = not rv 
            index = 0
            if not rv:
                limitForChange += 1
        index += 1
        yield rv

for i in range(0,4):
    g =  generateFalseTrueRangesAlternatively(20)
    print(next(g))
```

But I get only `False` values:

```
False
False
False
False
```

As a workaround, I wrote the following code, which generates a list :

```
def generateFalseTrueRangesAlternativelyList(limit):
    limitForChange = 1
    index = 0
    rv = False
    out = []
    for i in range(0, limit):
        if index == limitForChange:
            rv = not rv 
            index = 0
            if not rv:
                limitForChange += 1
        index += 1
        out.append(rv)
    return out
l = generateFalseTrueRangesAlternativelyInList(6)
for i in range (0,6):
    print(l[i])
```

Which outputs:

```
False
True
False
False
True
True
```

**Questions**

What is wrong with my `generateFalseTrueRangesAlternatively` function ?

How could it be modified to behave like the `generateFalseTrueRangesAlternativelyInList` but without creating a list ?

Is there something I did not understand with `yield` usage and what ?

Actually, my curiosity needs to be satisfied by answering this fundamental question: why ?

(My Python version: 3.5.4)

Comment: side note: [camelCase is generally frowned upon in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it is a pity that you deleted your answer as it seemed to be much more pythonic than my code. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You code is fine; the usage of generator is wrong.

Just iterate it:

```
for i in generateFalseTrueRangesAlternatively(20):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I was so dumb ! LOL Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

In the first snippet, you should only call the generator once, outside the `for`-loop, then use the `next` calls to obtain successive `yield`ed values:

```
g = generateFalseTrueRangesAlternatively(20)
for i in range(4):
    print(next(g))
```

Also note you can omit the lower bound of the `range` if it is zero.

Comment: That is the correct answer but just one minute slower than the accepted one, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a simplified implementation like this because it's much easier to understand and your original `generateFalseTrueRangesAlternatively` doesn't yield the correct values:

```
def alternate_trues_and_falses(limit):
    for i in range(1, limit + 1):
        for j in range(i):
            yield True
        for j in range(i):
            yield False

>>> list(alternate_trues_and_falses(2))
[True, False, True, True, False, False]

>>> for value in alternate_trues_and_falses(2):
...     print(value)
...
True
False
True
True
False
False
```

Comment: I'd explicitly skip `i == 0` (which is essentially a no-op) with `range(1, limit + 1)`.