# Assign variable names and data in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to load data into datasets in Python. My data is arranged by years. I want to assign variable names in a loop. Here's what it should look like in pseudocode:

```
import pandas as pd
for i in range(2010,2017):
    Data+i = pd.read_csv("Data_from_" +str(i) + ".csv")
    # Stores data from file "Data_from_YYYY.csv" as dataset DataYYYY.
```

The resulting datasets would be `Data2010` - `Data2017`.

Comment: You can't. Well, at least, you definitely shouldn't (using `exec` is dangerous). What's wrong with a dictionary `data = {}; for i in range(2010, 2017): data[i] = pd.read_csv("Data_from_" +str(i) + ".csv")`?

Comment: There are canonical ways which aren't risky the way that `exec` is, see my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, using a dictionary works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is possible, **it is not a good idea**. Code with dynamically-generated variable names is difficult to read and maintain. That said, you could do it using the `exec` function, which executes code from a string. This would allow you to dynamically construct your variables names using string concatenation.

However, you really should use a dictionary instead. This gives you an object with dynamically-named keys, which is much more suited to your purposes. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
Data = {}
for i in range(2010,2017):
    Data[i] = pd.read_csv("Data_from_" +str(i) + ".csv")
    # Stores data from file "Data_from_YYYY.csv" as dataset DataYYYY.

# Access data like this:
Data[2011]
```

You should also use snake_case for variable names in Python, so `Data` should be `data`.

If you *really* wanted to dynamically generate variables, you could do it like this. (But you aren't going to, right?)

```
import pandas as pd
for i in range(2010,2017):
    exec("Data{} = pd.read_csv(\"Data_from_\" +str(i) + \".csv\")".format(i))
    # Stores data from file "Data_from_YYYY.csv" as dataset DataYYYY.
```

You can do this without `exec` too; have a look at Jooks' answer.

Comment: *Code with dynamically-generated variable names is difficult to read and maintain.* This can't be said loudly enough.

Comment: To wit: python uses `snake_case`, not `camelCase`.

Comment: @jooks Whoops, I'll change my answer. Been doing much more C# lately!

Comment: @AaronChristiansen [Relevant PEP 8 section regarding use of snake_case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)

Comment: Haven't seen `exec()` before. Cool.

Also, code with dynamically-generated variables sounds like a footgun.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `globals`, `locals` or a `__init__` which uses `setattr` on `self` to assign the variables to an instance.

```
In [1]: globals()['data' + 'a'] = 'n'

In [2]: print dataa
n
```

---

```
In [3]: locals()['data' + 'b'] = 'n'

In [4]: print datab
n
```

---

```
In [5]: class Data(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
   ...:         for k, v in kwargs.items():
   ...:             setattr(self, k, v)
   ...:

In [6]: my_data = Data(a=1, b=2)

In [7]: my_data.a
Out[7]: 1
```

I would probably go the third route. You may be approaching your solution in an unconventional way, as this pattern is not very familiar, even if it is possible.