# How a function is given a name?

Tags: python, c, function

Which name is given a function that is separated by undescore.
function_name.

And to a function like FunctionName? and what would be the right one for python and ANSI C.??

Comment: It gets named `function_name`, simple as that. Which style to use is optional, use one and stick to it. There was some very interesting scientific report somewhere though (citation needed), which found out that programs written in camel case were less readable by the human brain.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Names.html#Names

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Comment: @Lundin: That proves I have a human brain. All those years of doubting are over!

Comment: Found it! "An Eye Tracking Study on camelCase and
under_score Identifier Styles" www.cs.kent.edu/~jmaletic/papers/ICPC2010-CamelCaseUnderScoreClouds.pdf. Quite a serious study!

Answer (score 3):

Function names like `func_one` are written in [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), while functions written like `FunctionOne` are written in Pascal case, which is a subset of [Camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) where the first letter is also uppercase.

Thanks to @abelenky for pointing out the initial error.

Comment: I've heard `FunctionOne` described as "Pascal Case", and `functionOne` would be "Camel Case" (because it has a "hump" in the middle).

Comment: I call `FunctionOne` "Upper Camel Case" but I'm not sure if that's a "standard" name for it.

Comment: @abelenky you're absolutely right, I made an error there. Will update.

Comment: @Kevin that's called Pascal Case :)

Comment: @Colin [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) says that upper camel case is a valid name for it too. I wasn't saying that Pascal Case was wrong, just that upper camel case is another name.

Comment: @Kevin you're right, the two seem to be interchangeable :)

Answer (score 1):

`function_name` is called a Snake Case. It is the recommended casing for Python.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)  for more enlightenment.

Comment: In before someone makes the Dromedary language, where the recommended style is camel case.

Comment: @Lundin OCaml ;)

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk Ach, all my bad ideas are already taken :(

Comment: @Lundin I'm sorry :(