# Python crawler (bs4, urlopen) malfunctions

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler

I am playing around with a webpage containing mtg cards and i am trying to extract some information about them.The following program works fine and i am able to crawl throw a page and retrieve all the desirable information:

```
import re
from math import ceil
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def NumOfNextPages(TotalCardNum, CardsPerPage):
    pages = ceil(TotalCardNum / CardsPerPage)
    return pages

URL = "xyz.com"
NumOfCrawledPages = 0

UClient = uReq(URL)  # downloading the url
page_html = UClient.read()
UClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


# Finds all the cards that exist in the webpage and stores them as a bs4 object
cards = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": ["iso-item", "item-row-view"]})
CardsPerPage = len(cards)


# Selects the card names, Power and Toughness, Set that they belong
for card in cards:

    card_name = card.div.div.strong.span.contents[3].contents[0].replace("\xa0 ", "")

    if len(card.div.contents) > 3:
        cardP_T = card.div.contents[3].contents[1].text.replace("\n", "").strip()
    else:
        cardP_T = "Does not exist"

    cardType = card.contents[3].text
    print(card_name + "\n" + cardP_T + "\n" + cardType + "\n")

# Trying to extract the next URL after this page, but there is not always a next page to retrieve, so an exception(IndexError) is produced due to our tries to access an index in a list that is empty, zero index is not available
try:
    URL_Next = "xyz.com/" + page_soup.findAll("li", {"class": 
"next"})[0].contents[0].get("href")
except IndexError:
    # End of crawling because of IndexError! Means that there is no next 
#page to crawl
    print("Crawling process completed! No more infomation to retrieve!")
else:
    print("The nex t URL is: " + URL_Next + "\n")
    NumOfCrawledPages += 1
finally:
    print("Moving to page : " + str(NumOfCrawledPages + 1) + "\n")

# We need to find the overall card number available, to find the number of 
#pages that we need to crawl
# we drag those infomation from a "div" tag with class "summary"

OverallCardInfo = (page_soup.find("div", {"class": "summary"})).text
TotalCardNum = int(re.findall("\d+", OverallCardInfo)[2])
NumOfPages = NumOfNextPages(TotalCardNum, CardsPerPage)
```

With this I can crawl the first page, which i manually give, and extract some info for the overall number of pages i need to crawl as well as the next url.

Ultimately i would like to give a starting point(webpage) and then the crawler would move into other webpages on its own. So I used the following for loop :

```
for i in range(0, NumOfPages):
    # The number of items shown by the search option on xyz.com can 
    #not be more than 10000
    if ((NumOfCrawledPages + 1) * CardsPerPage) >= 10000:
        print("Number of results provided can not exceed 10000!\nEnd of the 
crawling!")
        break

    if i == 0:
       Url = InitURL
    else:
        Url = URL_Next

    # opening up connection and crabbing the page
    UClient = uReq(Url)  # downloading the url
    page_html = UClient.read()
    UClient.close()

    # html parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    # Finds all the cards that exist in the webpage and stores them as a bs4 
#object
    cards = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": ["iso-item", "item-row-view"]})

    # Selects the card names, Power and Toughness, Set that they belong
    for card in cards:

        card_name = 
card.div.div.strong.span.contents[3].contents[0].replace("\xa0 ", "")

        if len(card.div.contents) > 3:
            cardP_T = card.div.contents[3].contents[1].text.replace("\n", 
"").strip()
        else:
            cardP_T = "Does not exist"

        cardType = card.contents[3].text
        print(card_name + "\n" + cardP_T + "\n" + cardType + "\n")

    # Trying to extract the next URL after this page, but there is not our #tries to access an index in a list that is empty, zero index is not available
    try:
        URL_Next = "xyz.com" + page_soup.findAll("li", {"class": "next"})[0].contents[0].get("href")
    except IndexError:
        # End of crawling because of IndexError! Means that there is no next #page to crawl
        print("Crawling process completed! No more infomation to retrieve!")
    else:
        print("The next URL is: " + URL_Next + "\n")
        NumOfCrawledPages += 1
        Url = URL_Next
    finally:
        print("Moving to page : " + str(NumOfCrawledPages + 1) + "\n")
```

The second code with the additional for loop runs without errors but the result is not what was expected. It returns the crawling results of the first page that i enter manually and it does not proceed further in other pages...

why does this happen?

The expected output is something like:

Dragonspeaker Shaman
P/T: 2/2
Creature - Human Barbarian Shaman

Dragonspeaker Shaman
P/T: 2/2
Creature - Human Barbarian Shaman

Dragonstalker
P/T: 3/3
Creature - Bird Soldier

The next URL is: xyz.com/......

Moving to page : 2

---------------------------------------------end of first page crawling

Dragonspeaker Shaman
P/T: 2/2
Creature - Human Barbarian Shaman

Dragonspeaker Shaman
P/T: 2/2
Creature - Human Barbarian Shaman

Dragonstalker
P/T: 3/3
Creature - Bird Soldier

The next URL is: xyz.com/......

Moving to page : 3

After retrieving this information from the manually given webpage it should go on with the next page saved at `Url` variable in the for loop. Instead it continues crawling the same page again and again. The counter works pretty well as it counts the number of pages crawled but the `Url` variable seem like it does not change value.

Comment: Have you tried removing the last line of the else clause in the try-except block? Also, use better naming conventions [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/160830/5645103) that can help both you and everyone understand your code

Comment: I have removed it and nothing changed.. Everything is running without errors but not as expected. Thanks for your reccomendations on variable naming. I will look into it!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I will edit the post to add the expected out put