# why some packages or functions in python are capitalized for the first letter, and some are not?

Tags: python

For example:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
```

is there any rule about the capitalization of the first letter?

Comment: Close-voters: Whether there is or isn't a rule regarding capitalization is *not* a matter of opinion.

Comment: `Request` is a class, `urlopen` is a function. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions

Comment: To expand upon @HåkenLid comment, classes are usually named using the PascalCase (or CamelCase) convention while functions are all lower cased separated with underscores.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the naming convention in Python for variable and function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answer is in [pep08 (python coding style guidelines)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - basically, classes are spelled in CamelCase, everything else in lower_with_underscores.

But note that (for various reasons), this convention is not always respected in Python itself (builtins and stdlib):

- quite a few classes are named in all_lower, notably the `datetime`, `date`, `time` and `timedelta` from the `datetime` package, all of the builtin types (`type`, `property`, `int`, `float`, `str`, `list`, `tuple`, `dict`, `set`, `object` etc)
- the `logging` package uses `mixedCase` for most functions and methods (ie `logging.getLogger()` which should be `logging.get_logger()` etc)

For the builtin types, there's at least an historical reason: most of those names where initially bound to functions, not to classes (I'm talking python 1.5.x or even older). For what it's worth, quite a few of them are actually *still* documented as being functions when they are not...

Answer (score 0):

The best practices in python is to use small letter in the name of functions but, when dealing with classes we capitalize the first letter.