# Python Ignoring Conditional Statement

Tags: python, string, list, conditional-statements

I am writing python code for algebraic expansion and I am running into a major error, python is not able to recognize the existence of a conditional it seems and I cannot figure out why

The code is:

```
def This(String):
    ReturnList = [char for char in String]
    Returner = []
    Counter = 0
    while len(ReturnList) > 1:
        TempString = ""
        for x in range(len(ReturnList)):
            Counter += 1
            if ReturnList[x] != "+" or ReturnList[x] != "-":
                print(ReturnList[x])
                TempString += str(ReturnList[x])
            else:
                break
        for x in range(Counter):
            ReturnList.pop(0)
        Returner.append(TempString)
        Counter = 0
    return Returner


here = "a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3"
print(here)
print(This(here))
```

The code is suppose to take the string, and then return sections of it, like this:

```
["+a^3","+3a^2b","+3ab^2","+b^3"]
```

however it doesnt seem to recognize + or - in the list, and just ignores it to return the full string

This is the print statements output:

```
a
^
3
 
+
 
3
a
^
2
b
 
+
 
3
a
b
^
2
 
+
 
b
^
3
```

Comment: `here = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3` doesn't set `here` to a string and is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: sorry I have a method that returns a string, I forgot to add in the parenthesis, one moment

Comment: Don't use `str(ReturnList[x])`, `ReturnList[x]` is already a character, so use: `TempString += ReturnList[x]`

Comment: `ReturnList[x] != "+" or ReturnList[x] != "-"` is always true because if it is `+`, it isn't `-` so at least one of the `or`ed parts is always true. You need `and` here.

Comment: Please use [python 's convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names) to name variables. They aren't classes, use lowercase and `_`. And use more meaningful names in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change `if ReturnList[x] != "+" or ReturnList[x] != "-":` to `if ReturnList[x] != "+" and ReturnList[x] != "-":`, it should work. The reason why the first one doesn't work is because it is always true, no matter what the character is.