# Naming python variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

Any tips on how I should properly be naming python variables? Like any correct forms or for clean code.

Like for instance

```
myNum = 1
```

or

```
mynum = 1
```

or

```
my_num = 1
```

Comment: As long as you can look at a variable and know what it is for, it probably doesn't matter. But if someone else will be looking at your code, you might want to make them more specific. [Python naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)

Comment: Python has an [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but it isn't mandatory. This question is opinion-based and therefore off-topic.

Comment: Dont use abstract naming , make your code human readable.

Answer (score 1):

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) recommends `my_num`. @Merp's comment is correct though. Be clear and consistent with whatever convention you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Well, **traditionally** developers follow the **'camelCase'** variable naming proceedure  in **most languages**, which is basically shown in your **1st code snippet**. However, there are **exceptions** in the wide range of programming languages out there in terms of norms that manifest themselves over time. In **Python**, most developers tend to use the variable naming shown in your 3rd code snippet, **separating** each word with an **underscore**.