# nested for loops and nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, enumerate

i am a new programmer trying to learn how to code still. I still don't quite know all of the technical info. I am trying to use a for loop on a list of dictionaries, and then inside of that loop, i want to create another loop that enumerates the dictionary keys. Inside of that loop, I then want to print the keys and values. I want the loop to break once the index reaches all of the points.

```
Dogs_in_Shelter = [{
               "type" : "poodle",
               "age" : "2", 
               "size" : "s", 
               
           }, 
           {    
               "type" : "pug",
               "age" : "7", 
               "size" : "m", 
           },
           {
               "type" : "lab",
               "age" : "10",
               "size" : "m", 
           }
               ]
for a in Dogs_in_Shelter:
 for index, a in enumerate(Dogs_in_Shelter):
   while (index <= 2): 
     print("{} {}".format(index,a["type"]))
     index += 1 
     break
```

what prints out is:

```
0 poodle
1 pug
2 lab
0 poodle
1 pug
2 lab
0 poodle
1 pug
2 lab
```

I want only the first three lines (with the key and value) , not the repetitions.
Any help for a learner?

*edit* Yes there is an easier way without the nesting loops however i still need to have them nested. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want repetitions you should get rid of the extra `for` and `while` loops. You only need one `for` loop: `for i, d in enumerate(Dogs_in_Shelter): print(i, d["type"])`

Answer (score 1):

No need of extra for loop and while loop.
enumerate function gives you index and by passing type key you can get its value.

```
for index, a in enumerate(Dogs_in_Shelter):
    print("{} {}".format(index, a["type"]))
```

---

Using nesting for loop.

Here I have used counter `length = 0`. Instead of while we should use if to check the counter.

```
length = 0
for a in Dogs_in_Shelter:
 for index, a in enumerate(Dogs_in_Shelter):
     if length <= 2 :
        print("{} {}".format(index,a["type"]))
        length += 1
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but i would still like to use the extra nested loops to complete this. Any other suggestions? TIA

Comment: what is the purpose of extra loop?

Comment: while loop  inside for loop will give repetitive  result. Instead use if- statement to check condition. I have updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You only need one `for` loop for what you want. `while` loop is also unnecessary. For example,

```py
for index, dog in enumerate(Dogs_in_Shelter):
    print(index, dog['type'])
```

2. For Python, we don't use upper letters for variables. FYI, [Python Naming Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)
   In this case, `Dogs_in_Shelter` should be `dogs_in_shelter`, or simply `dogs`.