# Python variable naming convention

Tags: python

What is meaning of this rule?
1.mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

Comment: Look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) and [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility

It means exactly what is says.  Function names should only be mixed case - like `doThing` or `computeAmount` if that style is already in use in the containing module, of which `threading.py` is an example.

This is to cater for modules which were written before PEP8.

In any modern Python code you should use `snake_case` for function and variable names.