# How to fix Python point class printing error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm making a point class in python and I am encountering an error with my makeVectorTo method (a method that takes a second Point as input, and returns a new Vector that goes from starting Point to the second Point). When I try to print  it, I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'h'.

How do I get rid of this and print it the way I want?

Here's my code:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

    def makeVectorTo(self, coor):
      dx = abs(self.x - coor.x)
      dy = abs(self.y - coor.y)
      newCoor = (dx, dy)
      return newCoor

###Testing Point Class###
vec1 = point1.makeVectorTo(point2)
print(vec1.h, vec1.v, "should be 0,3")
```

The error looked like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(vec1.h, vec1.v, "should be 0,3")
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'h'
```

Comment: What part of this code were you expecting to make a Vector?

Comment: At no point anywhere in your code do you declare an instance variable called `h` or `v`.

Comment: `makeVectorTo` returns a tuple. You can index into a tuple, but the error is self explanatory: A tuple doesn't have a `.h` or `.v` attribute you can access

Comment: nowhere in your code do you define what `vec1.h`, `vec1.v` are

Comment: if this is an assignment, they may be expecting you to implement some `Vector` class which has v, h, and position members and return it from `makeVectorTo()` [(which should practically be "snake cased" `make_vector_to()`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159745/4541045)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a tuple, so you should call by index your 'newCoor'

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

    def makeVectorTo(self, coor):
      dx = abs(self.x - coor.x)
      dy = abs(self.y - coor.y)
      newCoor = (dx, dy)
      return newCoor


point1=Point(1,1)
point2=Point(2,2)


###Testing Point Class###
vec1 = point1.makeVectorTo(point2)
# print(vec1.h, vec1.v, "should be 0,3")
print(vec1[0], vec1[1], "should be 0,3")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your code, you new to define your *Vector Class* too

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

    def makeVectorTo(self, coor):
      dx = abs(self.x - coor.x)
      dy = abs(self.y - coor.y)
      return Vector(dx, dy) # Note: calling Vector class


# Note: New Vector class
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, dx, dy):
        self.h = dx
        self.v = dy


# Testing
point1 = Point(0, 0)
point2 = Point(0, 3)
vec1 = point1.makeVectorTo(point2)
print(vec1.h, vec1.v, "should be 0.0,3.0") # Note: expect floats here not int
```

Note: `abs` only remove -tive sign for a int. If you want to convert a float into proper number then use `int` or `round`