# Appending a list to another list returns an empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a list that stores user input to be later manipulated. However when the User inputs names into the temporary list, it updates showing that the nameList has been updated, but when i add the nameList to the concernList, it does not add anything but an empty List!
[Empty List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xqNx.png)

```
 concernList = []
nameList = []



def nameLoop():
    global concernList
    global nameList
    first = input("First Name: ")
    nameList.append(first)
    print(nameList)
    middle = input("Middle Initial: ")
    nameList.append(middle)
    print(nameList)
    last = input("Last Name: ")
    nameList.append(last)
    print(nameList)
    concernList.append(nameList)
    nameList.clear()

def siteMonitor():
    pass


nameLoop()

while True:
    newConcernInput = input("Add Another Concern? (y/n)")
    if (newConcernInput.lower() == 'y'):
        nameLoop()
        print("Type 'q' to stop adding concerns. ")

    if (newConcernInput.lower() == 'n'):
        monitorInput = input("Begin Background Monitoring? (y/n)")
        if (monitorInput == 'y'):
            siteMonitor()
        else:
            pass

    if (newConcernInput.lower() == 'q'):
        break

    for count in range(0, len(nameList)):
        pass

    print(concernList)
    print("Added To Concern List.")
```

Comment: Unrelated to the actual issue itself, but you may want to check out PEP8, the Python style guide, as your variable names don't follow the [usual stylistic conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`concernList.append(nameList)` doesn't create a second list - the newly added element is just a reference to the original list ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment)). This means that `nameList.clear()` will delete the contents of the same list that you just appended to `concernList`.

However, I don't see the need for a global `nameList` in the first place. This is how I would rewrite the code:

```py
concernList = []
nameList = []

def nameLoop():
    first = input("First Name: ")
    middle = input("Middle Initial: ")
    last = input("Last Name: ")
    return [first, middle, last]

def siteMonitor():
    pass

nameList = nameLoop()
concernList.append(nameList)

while True:
    newConcernInput = input("Add Another Concern? (y/n)")
    if newConcernInput.lower() == 'y':
        nameList = nameLoop()
        concernList.append(nameList)
        print("Type 'q' to stop adding concerns. ")
    
    if newConcernInput.lower() == 'n':
        monitorInput = input("Begin Background Monitoring? (y/n)")
        if monitorInput == 'y':
            siteMonitor()
        else:
            pass
    
    if newConcernInput.lower() == 'q':
        break
    
    for count in range(0, len(nameList)):
        pass
    
    print(concernList)
    print("Added To Concern List.")
```