# pythonic replacement for enums

Tags: python, enums

In my python script i am parsing a user created file and typically there will be some errors and there are cases were i warn the user to be more clear. In c i would have an enum like eAssignBad, eAssignMismatch, eAssignmentSignMix (sign mixed with unsigned). Then i would look the value up to print an error or warning msg. I link having the warningMsg in one place and i like the readability of names rather then literal values. Whats a pythonic replacement for this?

**Duplicate of**: [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python/38092#38092)

Comment: You probably just want a dict, but it's hard to tell without seeing your entire program/function as pseudocode. C and Python are *very* different, and the best way to accomplish a task in them is not going to be the same.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python

Comment: Multi-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+enum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one of the best enum implementations I've found so far:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/413486/

But, dare I ask, do you need an enum?

You could have a simple dict with your error messages and some integer constants with your error numbers.

```
eAssignBad = 0
eAssignMismatch = 1
eAssignmentSignMix = 2

eAssignErrors = {
    eAssignBad: 'Bad assignment',
    eAssignMismatch: 'Mismatched thingy',
    eAssignmentSignMix: 'Bad sign mixing'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try making a bunch of exception classes (all subclasses of Exception, perhaps through some common parent class of your own).  Each one would have an error message text appropriate for the occasion...