# Enumerations in python

Tags: python, enums

> **Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best way to implement an ‘enum’ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python)

Whats the recognised way of doing enumerations in python?

For example, at the moment I'm writing a game and want to be able to move "up", "down", "left" and "right".  I'm using strings because I haven't yet figured out how enumerations work in python, and so my logic is littered with things like this:

```
def move(self, direction):
    if direction == "up":
        # Do something
```

I want to replace `"up"` with something like `Directions.up`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
class Directions:
    up = 0
    down = 1
    left = 2
    right =3
```

Answer (score 69):

**UPDATE 1**: Python 3.4 will have a built-in well designed [enum library](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/enum.html#module-enum).  The values always know their name and type; there is an integer-compatible mode but the recommended default for new uses are singletons, unequal to any other object.

**UPDATE 2**: Since writing this I realized the critical test for enums is *serialization*.  Other aspects can be refactored later, but if your enum goes into files / onto the wire, ask yourself up front what should happen if it's deserialized by an older/newer version (that might support a different set of values)...

---

If you are sure that you need an enum, others have answered *how* to do it.
But let's see *why* you want them?  Understanding the motivation will help with choosing the solution.

- **Atomic values** - in C, small numbers are easy to pass around, strings aren't.
  In Python, strings like "up" are perfectly good for many uses.
  Moreover, any solution that ends up with just a number is worse for debugging!
- **Meaningful values** - in C, you frequently *have* to deal with existing magic
  numbers, and just want some syntax sugar for that.  That's not the case here.
  However, there *is* other meaningful information you might want to associate with
  directions, e.g. the (dx,dy) vector - more on that below.
- **Type checking** - in C, enums help catching invalid values at compile time.
  But Python generally prefers sacrificing compiler checking for less typing.
- **Introspection** (doesn't exist in C enums) - you want to know all the valid values.
- **Completion** - the editor can show you the possible values and help you type them.

### Strings Redeemed (aka Symbols)

So, on the light side of Pythonic solutions, just use strings, and maybe have a list/set of all valid values:

```
DIRECTIONS = set(['up', 'down', 'left', 'right'])

def move(self, direction):
    # only if you feel like checking
    assert direction in DIRECTIONS
    # you can still just use the strings!
    if direction == 'up':
        # Do something
```

Note that the debugger would tell you that the function was called with 'up' as its argument.  Any solution where `direction` is actually `0` is much *worse* than this!

In the LISP family of languages, this usage is dubbed **symbols** - atomic objects usable as easily as numbers would be, *but carrying a textual value*.  (To be precise, symbols are string-like but a separate type.  However, Python routinely uses regular strings where LISP would use symbols.)

### Namespaced Strings

You can combine the idea that `'up'` is better than `0` with the other solutions.

If you want to catch mispellings (at run time):

```
UP = 'up'
...
RIGHT = 'right'
```

And if you want to insist on typing a prefix to get completion, put the above in a class:

```
class Directions:
    UP = "up"
    ...
    RIGHT = "right"
```

or just in a separate file, making it a module.

A module allows lazy users to do `from directions import *` to skip the prefix - up to you whether you consider this a plus or minus...  (I personally would hate to be forced to type `Directions.UP` if I'm using it frequently).

### Objects with functionality

What if there is useful information/functionality associated with each value?
"right" is not just one of 4 arbitrary values, it's the positive direction on the X axis!

If what you are doing in that `if` is something like:

```
def move(self, direction):
    if direction == 'up':
        self.y += STEP
    elif direction == 'down':
        self.y -= STEP
    elif direction == 'left':
        self.x -= STEP
    elif direction == 'right':
        self.x += STEP
```

than what you'd really like to write is:

```
def move(self, direction):
    self.x += direction.dx * STEP
    self.y += direction.dy * STEP
```

and that's it!

So you want to stuff this into either **instances**:

```
# Written in full to give the idea.
# Consider using collections.namedtuple
class Direction(object):
    def __init__(self, dx, dy, name):
        self.dx = dx
        self.dy = dy
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

UP = Direction(0, 1, "up")
DOWN = Direction(0, -1, "down")
LEFT = Direction(-1, 0, "left")
RIGHT = Direction(1, 0, "right")
```

or just **classes**:

```
class Direction(object):
    pass

class Up(Direction):
    dx = 0
    dy = 1

...

class Right(Direction):
    dx = 1
    dy = 0
```

Remember that in Python, classes are also objects (distinct from any other object), and you can compare them: `direction == Up` etc.

Generally, instances are probably cleaner, but if your enumerated concepts have some hierarchical relationship, sometimes modeling them directly with classes is very nice.

Comment: this is a great answer. most enum patterns are not very pythonic

Comment: +1 Nice! Lots more can be read elsewhere about individual approaches, but this is a very thoughtful, er, enumeration of the issues involved in a variety of approaches.

Answer (score 17):

I gave a +1 to Kugel, but another leaner option is

```
dirUp, dirDown, dirLeft, dirRight = range(4)
```

- - - (Some time passes)

So I was thinking...we have an obvious DRY violation here in that we already specify four items on the LHS, and then again specify four on the RHS.   What happens if we add items in the future?  What happens when someone else adds them, and maybe they are more sloppy than ourselves?   One obvious way to remove the DRY violation is to use the list of enums themselves to assign their values:

```
>>> enums = ['dirUp', 'dirDown']
>>> for v, k in enumerate(enums):
...     exec(k + '=' + str(v))
...     
>>> print dirDown
1
>>> print dirUp
0
```

If you can stomach using `exec()` for this, then fine.  If not, then use the other approach.  This current discussion is all academic anyway.   However, there is still a problem here.  What if the enums are used throughout a great body of source code, and some other programmer comes along and inserts a new value between `dirUp` and `dirDown`?  This will cause misery because the mapping between the names of the enums and the enums themselves will be wrong.   Bear in mind that that remains a problem even in the original simple solution.

Here, we have the novel idea of using the builtin `hash()` function to determine our enum value as an int, and we use the text name of the enum itself to determine the hash:

```
>>> for k in enums:
...     exec(k + '=' + str(hash(k)))
... 
>>> dirUp
-1147857581
>>> dirDown
453592598
>>> enums = ['dirUp', 'dirLeft', 'dirDown']
>>> for k in enums:
...     exec(k + '=' + str(hash(k)))
... 
>>> dirUp
-1147857581
>>> dirDown
453592598
>>> dirLeft
-300839747
>>>
```

Notice that we inserted a new value between `dirUp` and `dirDown`, i.e. `dirLeft`, and our original mapping values for the first two *did not change*.

I may actually use this in my own code.   Thanks to the OP for posting the question.

- - - (Some more time passes)

Beni Cherniavsky-Paskin made some very good comments:

- Python's default `hash()` is not stable across platforms (dangerous for persistence applications)
- The possibility of collisions is always present.

I tend to agree with both observations.  His suggestion is to use the strings themselves (I really like the self-documenting behaviour of using the values) as the hash, and so the code becomes the following (note we use a set instead of a list, to enforce uniqueness):

```
>>> items=('dirUp','dirDown','dirLeft','dirRight')
>>> for i in items:
        exec('{}="{}"'.format(i,i))
>>> dirDown
'dirDown'
```

It is also trivial to put these in a namespace, so as to avoid collisions with other code:

```
>>> class Direction():
        for i in ('dirUp','dirDown','dirLeft','dirRight'):
            exec('{}="{}"'.format(i,i))

>>> Direction.dirUp
'dirUp'
```

The length of the cryptographic hash he mentions can be seen here:

```
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> crypthash = md5('dirDown'.encode('utf8'))
>>> crypthash.hexdigest()
'6a65fd3cd318166a1cc30b3e5e666d8f'
```

Comment: You could combine the two solutions. 

class Direction: up, down, left, right = range(4)

Comment: Why use numbers and not strings?  A hash is strictly worse than the original string.  It gives you "compression", but it's a lie - there is good chance of collisions.  A cryptographic hash would be ok, but it's long in itself.

Comment: Note also that `hash()` is not stable accross python implementations and versions.  So serializing structures containing such enums would be a bad idea.

Comment: You made very good comments, thank you.  I have modified my post.

Answer (score 14):

The [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) object can provide such a namespace:

```
>>> import collections
>>> dircoll=collections.namedtuple('directions', ('UP', 'DOWN', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT'))
>>> directions=dircoll(0,1,2,3)
>>> directions
directions(UP=0, DOWN=1, LEFT=2, RIGHT=3)
>>> directions.DOWN
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 13):

This is simple and effective:

```
class Enum(object):
  def __init__(self, *keys):
    self.__dict__.update(zip(keys, range(len(keys))))
```

Usage:

```
>>> x = Enum('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bat')
>>> x.baz
2
>>> x.bat
3
```

Comment: (Incidentally, that's not my invention.  In fact, I'm reasonably sure that it originated with GVR his bad self.)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Python 2.6+ then you can use [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). They have the advantage having fixed number of properties, and when you need all enum values, you can use it like a tuple.

For more control over enum values, you may create your own enumeration class.

```
def enum(args, start=0):
    class Enum(object):
        __slots__ = args.split()

        def __init__(self):
            for i, key in enumerate(Enum.__slots__, start):
                setattr(self, key, i)

    return Enum()

>>> e_dir = enum('up down left right')
>>> e_dir.up
0
>>> e_dir = enum('up down left right', start=1)
>>> e_dir.up
1
```

Declaring `__slots__` seals your Enum class, no more attributes can be set to an object which was created from a class with `__slots__` property.

Your `Enum` class can also be `namedtuple` based, in that case you also get the features of a tuple. See [`namedtuple docs`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) on subclassing `namedtuple`