# using python how to give 0, 1 , 2 for ternary variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, enums, binary

I have `csv` file, with column names of: PH, K, Zn, S, Fe ...so on. For each column there hare 3 different types of output, for example:

```
PH       S       Zn     Fe         Cu   Mn
Acidic   Low    Low     Medium  High    Medium
Alkaline High   Medium  Medium  High    High
Acidic  Medium  Low     Medium  High    High
Neutral High    Low     Medium  High    High
Acidic   Low    Low     Medium  High    High
Acidic   Low    Low     Medium  High    High
Acidic  Medium  Medium  Medium  High    High
```

I want to give values of

```
Acidic = 0, Neutral = 1, Alkaline = 2
Low = 0, Medium = 1, High = 2
```

How to write a code which is automatic convert Acidic=0 , Neutral=1 , Alkaline=2?

Comment: 0 1 2 is not binary ... 0, 1 is binary

Comment: @CedricDruck, Oh, Okay, How to convert Low, Medium, High in terms of 0, 1, 2 ? is it possible?

Comment: intent or file format is not clear, please elaborate

Comment: I'd use dicts .. something like ph_dict = {'Acidic': 1, 'Neutral': 2, 'Alkaline': 3}

Comment: If you are working on some machine learning tasks and are using a library for that, `scikit-learn` and `pandas` have some inbuild functions for doing that.

Comment: @VivekKumar, yes I am working on same machine learning tasks, and using scikit-learn and pandas. but, I want specific numbers for acidic = 1 , neutral = 2 so on , so I am confuse

Answer (score 3):

Ok so something like

```
dicts = {
   'PH' : {'Acidic': 0, 'Alkaline': 1, 'Neutral': 2},
   'S': {'Low': 0, 'High': 1, 'Medium': 2},
   # etc
} 
with open(your_file) as file:
    table = []
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        new_row = {key: dicts[key][value] for (key, value) in row.items()}
        table.append(new_row)
```

Comment: Yes, that's actual Python code .. what's the question?

Comment: your_file means my file name is samplefile.csv so i have use with open (samplefile.csv) as file :   ?

Comment: you have to use some sort of path to your file, yes. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: and  reader = csv.DictReader(file)   so, here I have use file or something my path ?

Comment: no, file is the result of open(your_file), you just have to adapt the "your_file" variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136128/discussion-between-kiran-prajapati-and-cedric-druck).

Answer (score 1):

Python provides the [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) class.  Why you want to use Enums is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1970200/7311767).  In your case they would look something like:

**Code:**

```
from enum import Enum
PH = Enum('PH', 'Acidic Neutral Alkaline')
Concentration = Enum('Concentration', 'Low Medium High')
```

**Demo Code:**

```
print(PH['Acidic'].value)
print(Concentration['Medium'].value)
```

**Produces:**

```
1
2
```

**Demo Code2:**

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    ph = PH(i)
    concentration = Concentration(i)
    print(ph, ph.name, ph.value)
    print(concentration, concentration.name, concentration.value)
```

**Produces:**

```
PH.Acidic Acidic 1
Concentration.Low Low 1
PH.Neutral Neutral 2
Concentration.Medium Medium 2
PH.Alkaline Alkaline 3
Concentration.High High 3
```

Comment: Can I use 1,2,3, numbers output for my next analysis using enum?

Comment: Yes, the `value` is a number, see examples.