# Python's enum equivalent

Tags: python, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best way to implement an ‘enum’ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python)

What is the Python idiom for a list of differently indexed names (like Enum in C/C++ or Java)?

Clarification: I want a property of a value to be set to a restricted range, such as card suites `Heart, Club, Spade, Diamond`. I could represent it with an int in range 0..3, but it would allow out of range input (like 15).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
class Suite(object): pass

class Heart(Suite): pass
class Club(Suite): pass
```

etc.

A class in python is an object. So you can write

```
x=Heart
```

etc.

Answer (score 8):

here is very same popular question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python/2182437#2182437)

**Edit**:

```
class Suite(set):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self:
            return name
        raise AttributeError

s1 = Suite(['Heart', 'Club', 'Spade', 'Diamond'])
s1.Heart
```