# Is there any way to create user defined data types in python without using a class

Tags: python, types

Is it possible to create user defined data types in python without using class, like using structure. Please explain, because I am new in python. Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python User-Defined Data Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224571/python-user-defined-data-type)

Comment: No, *types are classes in python*

Answer (score 0):

To create a type without using a `class` statement, you can use the [`type` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

> `class type(name, bases, dict)`
>
> With three arguments, return a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the `class` statement. The *name* string is the class name and becomes the `__name__` attribute; the *bases* tuple itemizes the base classes and becomes the `__bases__` attribute; and the *dict* dictionary is the namespace containing definitions for class body and is copied to a standard dictionary to become the `__dict__` attribute. For example, the following two statements create identical `type` objects:
>
> ```
> class X:
>     a = 1
>
> X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))
> ```
>
> See also [Type Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-type-objects).

Comment: Hey @wjandrea Thanks.

Comment: This *creates a class*, it's exactly equivalent to the class definition statement as explained in the document you are quoting

Comment: @juanpa I interpreted the question as "without using a class *statement*". That's the only way it makes sense to me. I edited the answer to clarify my assumption.