# Recognize which model object is clicked in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have many overlapping shapes representing irrelevant background items on a canvas. I also have a pattern of non-overlapping circles, each of which is a "hole". Each "hole" sprite (circle) has an associated "hole" object, though never explicitly in the code. (side note: I would love to have a logical association between model and view with these objects, but haven't found a smart way to do that). Each "hole" is different, and has different effects.

There is a small circular "ball" which can be dragged into any "hole". I found how to drag and drop from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740855/board-drawing-code-to-move-an-oval/6789351#6789351). I need to find which hole the ball went into.

The best way I have found to do that so far is to:

- create a dict mapping the coordinates of the center of the hole sprite to the hole object
- tag each hole like this:

`t=("hole", "hole_at_{}_{}".format(x, y))`

- on releasing the ball, do this:

  def on_ball_release(self, event):
      '''Process button event when user releases mouse holding ball.'''

  ```
  # use small invisible rectangle and find all overlapping items
  items = self._canvas.find_overlapping(event.x - 10, event.y - 10, event.x + 10, event.y + 10)

  for item in items:
      # there should only be 1 overlapping hole
      if "hole" in self._canvas.gettags(item):

          # get the coordinates from the tag
          coords = tuple([int(i) for i in self._canvas.gettags(item)[1].replace("hole_at_", "").split("_")])

          # get associated object using dictionary established before
          hole = self._hole_dict[coords]

          hole.process_ball()
          return
  ```

That seems very messy. I feel there should be some smarter way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't use Python, but many Tkinter questions can be answered in a useful from an experience with Tcl/Tk, which I have. In this case, it takes some more work to figure out whether what I would do in Tcl is easy to represent with Tkinter.

First, I wouldn't add "identifier tags" (`hole_at_...`): if I have model objects corresponding to canvas items, I would use the item *id* (which canvas returns during item creation) as an index, to be able to find an object for an item id without parsing tags. (And if I had to add string identifiers, even if I decided to make them from coordinates, I would use *that very string* as my dictionary key, to avoid reparsing it. Do we need coordinates later? Then make them properties of the `hole` object).

Second, I would use `pathName find` subcommand with *multiple* criteria to find (canvas id of) item which is tagged as `hole` *and* is nearest to the given point (`overlapping` is fine when we want to ignore drops too far from any hole, `closest` is for the case where nearest hole should be used even if it's not too near). Here is the problematic part: does Tkinter support multiple criteria in canvases' `$pathName find`?

Comment: I like your other suggestions, but the problem with using `find_closest` is the plethora of background objects that could be closer, but I am not interested in them.

Comment: Is there a more direct way to tie a model to its sprite than with a dict?

Comment: @BlackSheep that's why I suggested multi-criteria find: when it's given `withtag hole` as a first criteria and `closest x y ?halo? ?start?` as a second (that's all in TCL, sorry), it will consider nothing but *holes*.

Comment: @BlackSheep in TCL, it would be equivalent to a dict, more or less. As of Python, I wouldn't be surprised if it could create "proxy objects" for canvas items to save us trouble working with ids, but I have no idea whether it's actually possible.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko, @BlackSheep: the multi-criteria find can be done in Python by using the `find` method of the `Canvas` class, it won't be pretty but can be done. `mycanvas.find('withtag', 'hole', 'closest', x, y)`.