# Tkinter drag and drop

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop, tkinter-canvas

I'm working on a drag and drop function that will allow me to move items around on a canvas.I have it working (Kind of) but I move only slightly but the line shoots across the screen (And eventually off the visible part of the canvas so I cannot get to it. I'm not sure where to go from here. Below is the drag and drop code I've created so far:

```
def onPressToMove(self, event): #get initial location of object to be moved
    winX = event.x - self.workspace.canvasx(0)
    winY = event.y - self.workspace.canvasy(0)
    self.dragInfo["Widget"] = self.workspace.find_closest(event.x, event.y, halo = 5)[0]
    self.dragInfo["xCoord"] = winX
    self.dragInfo["yCoord"] = winY

def onReleaseToMove(self, event): #reset data on release
    self.dragInfo["Widget"] = None
    self.dragInfo["xCoord"] = 0
    self.dragInfo["yCoord"] = 0        

def onMovement(self, event):
    winX = event.x - self.workspace.canvasx(0)
    winY = event.y - self.workspace.canvasy(0)
    newX = winX - self.dragInfo["xCoord"]
    newY = winY - self.dragInfo["yCoord"]
    self.workspace.move(self.dragInfo["Widget"], newX, newY)
```

dragInfo is a dictionary I'm using to store the data. Originally I thought that translating the canvas coordinates to window coordinates would help, but it acts the same as without that stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6789351/7432) to the question "board drawing code to move an oval" shows how to drag an object on a canvas.

In your case, you're not resetting the base of the delta as you move the object. If the mouse moves one pixel to the right, you use `move` to move the mouse one pixel to the right.

Now, let's say you move it one more pixel to the right. This time, your calculation says the delta is 2 from the starting point even though you only actually moved the mouse one more pixel). Next time you move one pixel, you're calculating a delta of 3, and so on.

The solution is simple: reset `dragInfo["xCoord"]` and `dragInfo["yCoord"]` while it is moving, since you only want to compute the delta to its previous position, not the original starting position.

```
def onPressToMove(self, event): #get initial location of object to be moved
    winX = event.x - self.canvas.canvasx(0)
    winY = event.y - self.canvas.canvasy(0)
    self.dragInfo["Widget"] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y, halo = 5)[0]

    # reset the starting point for the next move
    self.dragInfo["xCoord"] = winX
    self.dragInfo["yCoord"] = winY
```

Comment: I read that, but that doesn't really answer my question. My question is, is there a reason why it's moving so quickly. It's useless to drag something if anything more than the slightest movement makes it shoot across the canvas and out of sight.

Comment: @user2148990: have you printed out the values you're using in the call to `move` to see if they are what you expect them to be?

Comment: It's always the simple things that are easy to overlook. Resetting the starting points worked perfectly now. Thank you!