# tkinter listbox drag and drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, tkinter

I'm trying to make a listbox with the ability to do drag and drop onto a canvas. I've done drag and drop before, but it was only between canvas.create_text loosely based on the code for a this checkers program I found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740855/board-drawing-code-to-move-an-oval/6789351#6789351) I've seen a couple of questions about drag and drop listboxes but they only deal with changing the order of elements in the listbox. What I'm dealing with is a listbox which has a list of names, and a canvas with some create_text objects on the canvas, and I want to be able to drag a name from the listbox onto the canvas. If figure I'd need to make a Listbox subclass, but I'm unsure of where to go from there.

So I've got a DialogWindow (subclass of Toplevel), and have my canvas and listbox in the DialogWindow. I've conjured up a way of getting a name from the listbox: when I click on a name, I convert it to a canvas.create_text object and then drag that. My issue is the drop. I try to use the canvas.canvasx to convert to canvas coordinates but it hasn't worked for me. x and y are still in listbox coordinates.

```
def onRelease(self, event): 
    x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = self.canvas.canvasx(event.y)
    print(event.x, event.y)
    print(x, y) #Prints the same thing as the previous line
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to address getting the proper coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to drag and drop boils down to needing to do three things:

- bind on `<ButtonPress-1>` to select the item to be dragged
- bind on `<B1-Motion>` to do the drag
- bind on `<ButtonRelease-1>` to do the drop

None of this requires any subclassing. All of these bindings are on the listbox widget. You'll probably want to create an instance of `Toplevel` with a text label in it and the window decorations removed (using `wm_overrideredirect(True)`) to represent the item being dragged.

On the drop, you'll need to convert the coordinates of the mouse to canvas coordinates using the `canvasx` and `canvasy` methods of the canvas. Instead of starting with `event.x` and `event.y` (which are relative to the listbox), use the `winfo_pointerxy` method to get the screen coordinates of the mouse, then do a little math.

Here's an example of how you could do the drop:

```
def _on_drag_drop(self, event):
    i = self.listbox.curselection()[0]
    text = self.listbox.get(i)
    wx, wy = self.canvas.winfo_rootx(), self.canvas.winfo_rooty()
    x,y = self.winfo_pointerxy()
    cx = self.canvas.canvasx(x-wx)
    cy = self.canvas.canvasy(y-wy)
    self.canvas.create_text(cx,cy,text=text, anchor="sw")
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
```