# how to drag and drop an image in tkinter using python

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I need to drag an one image and drop it into on an another image and also get an x-axis,y-axis value of position which i dropped image in tkinter using python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the tkinter documentation about events and bindings?

Comment: i created image on canvas in tkinter.I have to drag an image and to drop it onto another place(x-axis,y-axis).

Comment: possible duplicate of [board-drawing code to move an oval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740855/board-drawing-code-to-move-an-oval)

Comment: ok this just stuck my mind..maybe wrong approach but: could try & bind the `<ButtonRelease-1>` event maybe