# How do you use a button to move items on a canvas in Python?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm trying to modify an example script that was posted here:

[board-drawing code to move an oval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740855/board-drawing-code-to-move-an-oval/6789351#6789351)

The original script allowed you to click and drag objects around the canvas.  I changed it so that a button would move the first object, but I get a button error:
TypeError: button_move() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
I don't understand what the second argument should be.

Here is the modified script:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    '''Illustrate how to drag items on a Tkinter canvas'''

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create a canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # this data is used to keep track of an 
        # item being dragged
        self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}

        # create a couple of movable objects
        self._create_token((100, 100), "white")
        self._create_token((200, 100), "black")

        # add bindings for clicking, dragging and releasing over
        # any object with the "token" tag
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_token_press)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_token_release)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<B1-Motion>", self.on_token_motion)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.canvas.button2 = tk.Button(self.canvas, text="Button Test",
                                 command=self.button_move)
        self.canvas.button2.config(bg="cyan",fg="black")
        self.canvas.button2.pack(side='top')

        self.canvas.tag_bind("button2", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.button_move)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def _create_token(self, coord, color):
        '''Create a token at the given coordinate in the given color'''
        (x,y) = coord
        self.canvas.create_oval(x-25, y-25, x+25, y+25, 
                                outline=color, fill=color, tags="token")

    def on_token_press(self, event):
        '''Begining drag of an object'''
        # record the item and its location
        self._drag_data["item"] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

    def on_token_release(self, event):
        '''End drag of an object'''
        # reset the drag information
        self._drag_data["item"] = None
        self._drag_data["x"] = 0
        self._drag_data["y"] = 0

    def on_token_motion(self, event):
        '''Handle dragging of an object'''
        # compute how much the mouse has moved
        delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
        delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        # record the new position
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def button_move(self, event):
        '''Handle dragging of an object'''
        # set movement amount
        delta_x = 15
        delta_y = 15
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        #self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        self.canvas.move(self._drag_data[1], delta_x, delta_y)
        # record the new position
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command=` executes function without `event` but you assign function which expects `event` - `command=self.button_move` -> `def button_move(self, event)`

But `bind` executes the same function with `event` so you need this function with `event`.

**Solution:** use default value for event, ie `None`

```
def button_move(self, event=None):
```

But you can't use `event.x`, `event.y` in this function if you what to execute with `command=`

Comment: Adding "event=None" is the key.  I also commented out "self._drag_data["x"] = event.x" and "self._drag_data["y"] = event.y" in the "button_move" function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code using furas's advice:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    '''Illustrate how to drag items on a Tkinter canvas'''

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create a canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # this data is used to keep track of an 
        # item being dragged
        self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}

        # create a couple of movable objects
        self._create_token((100, 100), "white")
        self._create_token((200, 100), "black")

        # add bindings for clicking, dragging and releasing over
        # any object with the "token" tag
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_token_press)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_token_release)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<B1-Motion>", self.on_token_motion)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.canvas.button2 = tk.Button(self.canvas, text="Button Test",
                                 command=self.button_move)
        self.canvas.button2.config(bg="cyan",fg="black")
        self.canvas.button2.pack(side='top')

        self.canvas.tag_bind("button2", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.button_move)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def _create_token(self, coord, color):
        '''Create a token at the given coordinate in the given color'''
        (x,y) = coord
        self.canvas.create_oval(x-25, y-25, x+25, y+25, 
                                outline=color, fill=color, tags="token")

    def on_token_press(self, event):
        '''Begining drag of an object'''
        # record the item and its location
        self._drag_data["item"] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

    def on_token_release(self, event):
        '''End drag of an object'''
        # reset the drag information
        self._drag_data["item"] = None
        self._drag_data["x"] = 0
        self._drag_data["y"] = 0

    def on_token_motion(self, event):
        '''Handle dragging of an object'''
        # compute how much the mouse has moved
        delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
        delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        # record the new position
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def button_move(self, event=None):
        '''Handle dragging of an object'''
        # set movement amount
        delta_x = 15
        delta_y = 15
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        #self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        #self.canvas.move(self._drag_data[1], delta_x, delta_y)
        self.canvas.move(1, delta_x, delta_y) # moves item 1, when cursor is over token
        # record the new position
        #self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        #self._drag_data["y"] = event.y
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: better edit question and apped new code in question.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure a callback such as `button_move()` as the button's `command`, the only argument given to it when it's called is `self`, just as if you called it like this:

```
self.button_move()
```

But because `button_move()` also expects an `event` argument, you get the following error:

```
TypeError: button_move() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given).
```

So removing the `event` parameter from `button_move()` definition would be the first step.

Also, since `event` wouldn't be in `button_move()` scope, you should remove these two lines:

```
self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
self._drag_data["y"] = event.y
```

Finally, you need the id from the canvas object you want to move in order for the `self.canvas.move()` line to work. I suggest you remove the line

```
self._drag_data["item"] = None
```

from `on_token_release()`, so that the id from the canvas object that was last clicked is saved in `self._drag_data["item"]`. Then all you need to do is check if `self._drag_data["item"]` is not None before trying to call `canvas.move()`.

Applying all these changes yields the following code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    '''Illustrate how to drag items on a Tkinter canvas'''

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create a canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # this data is used to keep track of an
        # item being dragged
        self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}

        # create a couple of movable objects
        self._create_token((100, 100), "white")
        self._create_token((200, 100), "black")

        # add bindings for clicking, dragging and releasing over
        # any object with the "token" tag
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_token_press)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_token_release)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<B1-Motion>", self.on_token_motion)

        self.canvas.button2 = tk.Button(self.canvas, text="Button Test",
                                 command=self.button_move)
        self.canvas.button2.config(bg="cyan",fg="black")
        self.canvas.button2.pack(side='top')

        self.canvas.tag_bind("button2", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.button_move)

    def _create_token(self, coord, color):
        '''Create a token at the given coordinate in the given color'''
        (x,y) = coord
        self.canvas.create_oval(x-25, y-25, x+25, y+25,
                                outline=color, fill=color, tags="token")

    def on_token_press(self, event):
        '''Begining drag of an object'''
        # record the item and its location
        self._drag_data["item"] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

    def on_token_release(self, event):
        '''End drag of an object'''
        # reset the drag information
        self._drag_data["x"] = 0
        self._drag_data["y"] = 0

    def on_token_motion(self, event):
        '''Handle dragging of an object'''
        # compute how much the mouse has moved
        delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
        delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        # record the new position
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

    def button_move(self):
        if not self._drag_data["item"]:
            return

        '''Handle dragging of an object'''
        # set movement amount
        delta_x = 15
        delta_y = 15
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        #self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```