# How to document and use enum-like data types in Python?

Tags: python, enums, doxygen

Let's assume that the current code is using strings for parameters and you want to document their valid values.

Example

```
def MyFunc(region = None):
    if region in ['A','B','C', None]:
        # dosomething
    else:
        # complain about invalid parameter
```

Now the question is how can I improve this design in order to solve two problems:

- be able to use the auto-complete functionality in IDEs to auto-complete with possible values for the parameter.
- document the list of valid values for the parameter (currently the code is documented using doxygen)

Comment: IDE auto-complete is a waste of time.  There, I said it.  More importantly, please explain why region is a string.  There are a lot of choices for enumerating values like this.  Why did you choose a string?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a similar question:
[How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python)

It suggests implementing something like:

```
class MyClass :
    A = 0   """The Letter A"""
    B = 1   """The Letter B"""
    C = 2   """The Letter C"""
    D = 3   """The Letter D"""

variable = MyClass.A    # Ok
variable = MyClass.E    # Error
```

With this you get your IDE auto-complete as well.  (Which contrary to S.Lott's opinion, I use all the time... old java habit I guess).

It's considered poor style to use a docstring to restate the obvious, and I think in this case makes the code readability worse.  For more information on docstrings:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

If you're curious why there is no enum type in Python, you might check out the PEP:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0354/

Answer (score 2):

Enums are supported as of 3.4: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html