# what is pythonic way to communicate between modules?

Tags: python, interface, implementation

let's assume following C code:

```
// events.h
enum Events  {eOne, eTwo, eThree};
enum Events getEvent(void);
```

...

```
//ctrl.c
#include "events.h"

void ctrl(void)
{
    switch(getEvent()) 
    {
    case eOne:
        // ...
        break;
    case eTwo:
        // ...
        break;
    case eThree:
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        ;
    }
}
```

What is pythonic way to implement this? The simple way for me, is to use strings instead of enums, but how can I be sure that all strings are typed correctly (i.e. are the same in all files)?

Comment: Are you asking for the pythonic way to implement `enum`s, the pythonic way to implement `switch` statements, the pythonic way to communicate between modules, or something else?  Could you supply more code?  There are different solutions depending on what you are doing.

Comment: @ivand58: What is the use case that you think of regarding communication between modules?

Comment: Can you provide a user scenario? From the look of it, I think all you need is to install [`carrot`](http://ask.github.com/carrot/introduction.html)... ;) but I might be missing something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Python code is similar to how your C code interacts.  To use variables from another module you need to first import that module.

```
// events.py
class Events:
    eOne, eTwo, eThree = range(3)

def getEvent():
    # add code for getEvent here (might have been in events.c for C code)
    return some_event
```

...

```
// ctrl.py
from events import Events, getEvent
def ctrl():
    event = getEvent()
    if event == Events.eOne:
        # ...
    elif event == Events.eTwo:
        # ...
    elif event == Events.eThree:
        # ...
    else:
        # default
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Animal:
    DOG=1
    CAT=2

x = Animal.DOG
```

source: [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Make the strings constants and then you can reference them by name so you don't have magic strings hanging around in the source code. You could define these constants in a common module or class.