# String options for function input python

Tags: python, tab-completion

I am writing a Python function (2.7) where one of the input parameters is a string. The string value should be one of a few values.

i.e. the parameter, in this case "sort" could be any from the list ['first author' 'last author' 'title'] ( the list is actually a bit longer)

Is there a nice way of helping the user supply this input (via tab completion). The ultimate goal is to try and improve the interface for the user so that it is easier for them to use my code and to make less mistakes.

**Option 1: Define constants**

This might be the best option but there are multiple ways of doing this. My approach is below.

I'm considering creating constants in the module in which the function resides, but this seems messy. My current solution is to include a class with the options, but this makes the input really long, unless I cheat and make the class something nonsensical and short (which is what I've done but it seems wrong and non-obvious). What should I do?

**Option 2: Via interpreted documentation**

NOTE: I don't think this option actually exists ...

I like the idea of placing code in the documentation which editors could use to perform tab-complete, but I'm not aware of this option existing.

**Other options?**

Current code (roughly):

```
class C(): 
    SORT_FIRST_AUTHOR = 'first author'
    SORT_LAST_AUTHOR  = 'last author'
    SORT_TITLE        = 'title'

 #Ideally these might be selected by: my_module.search.sort_option.FIRST_AUTHOR instead of my_module.C.FIRST_AUTHOR but that's REALLY long


def search(query_string,sort = None): #Changed sort = [], to sort = None per comments
```

UPDATE: (Trying to clarify the question)

This is somewhat similar to this question, although I think the answers diverge from what I'm looking for because of the specifics of the question.

[Pythonic way to have a choice of 2-3 options as an argument to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522877/pythonic-way-to-have-a-choice-of-2-3-options-as-an-argument-to-a-function)

Ideally, I would like the definition of search() to allow tab completion on "sort" by having specifications, something like:

```
def search(....):
   """
   :param sort:
   :values sort: 'first author'|'last author'|'title'
   """
```

But, I'm not aware of that actually being a valid documentation option.

alternatively, I could define some constants that allows this so that the call becomes:

search(my_a,my_b,package_name.C.SORT_FIRST_AUTHOR)

But this seems ugly and wrong.

So when you want the user to pass in one out of a set of options, how do you do it?

Comment: for starters, don't have `[]` be the default value for `sort`, [because reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: Is it just me, or is it not quite clear what you're asking?

Comment: @roippi This call is going to a server. Omission of the parameter in the http request indicates that the default value should be used.

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. Please edit your question to a single topic, i.e. drop all this talk of tab-complete if your question is really about how to use function arguments.

Comment: @Jimbo you misunderstand.  Read the link.  Mutable default arguments are bugs waiting to happen.

Comment: @roippi, I was looking for that exact example! I couldn't find it. Point noted. I didn't realize "because reasons" was a link since I had visited that page a while back and the vlink color is hard for me to see relative to normal text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on a user to correctly type a string literal is usually a bad idea as it can result in silent errors if the string contains a typo.

It is common to define uppercase variables at the module level, for instance the socket module has

```
socket.SOCK_STREAM
socket.SOCK_DGRAM
socket.SOCK_RAW
```

These are passed to functions as parameters, and could easily contain string values.

> "Ideally these might be selected by: my_module.search.sort_option.FIRST_AUTHOR instead of my_module.C.FIRST_AUTHOR but that's REALLY long"

Yes that first option seems a bit long. `mymodule.SORT_FIRST_AUTHOR` seems reasonable though, and using class variables could be appropriate if the constants are constrained to that class and/or if the class is likely to be imported from the module independently.

```
from mymodule import Searcher
s = Searcher(..., Searcher.SORT_FIRST_AUTHOR)
```

Prefixing the constants with a common term (like SORT) will aide editors when tab completing entries and makes the constants more descriptive.

You could also consider using a [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
>>> SortOpts = namedtuple('SortOpts', ('FIRST_AUTHOR', 'LAST_AUTHOR'))
>>> SORT_OPT = SortOpts(FIRST_AUTHOR=0, LAST_AUTHOR=1)
>>> SORT_OPT.FIRST_AUTHOR
0
>>> SORT_OPT.FIRST_AUTHOR = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

This has the advantage of protecting the attributes from being changed, however I don't think this will work with tab completion in most editors.

Comment: I think the key idea here is probably to promote my function to being the method of a new search class. This allows for hiding the constants in the class instead of in the module or as some other awkward constants class. Thanks!

Comment: If that makes sense for your application, then great - but as a user, I would prefer to use a function at the module level if possible over having to instantiate a class to call a method. You're the best judge though of what will work best.