# Python Functions, Param Type Checking + Strict Value Checking

Tags: python, string, function, types

I like to define parameter types when writing Python to give the reader an easy understanding of what should be passed into a function, and what the type of data is going to look like. For example,

```py
def reverse_string(string_to_reverse: str) -> str:
   ...
   return reversed_string
```

I have a special case however, where the function I am making is not only of the type `str`, but also should always be passed one of two string values. Anything else SHOULD throw and exception and let the user know something messed up.

In code, this should look like,

```py
>>> def some_func(test_string: str["test_string_1", "test_string_2"]) -> str:
...    return f"Valid string passed \'{test_string}\'"
...
>>> some_func("test_string_1") # ✔️
... "Valid string passed 'test_string_1'"
>>> some_func("test_string_2") # ✔️
... "Valid string passed 'test_string_2'"
>>> some_func("test_string_3") # ❌
... "EXCEPTION: SOME EXCEPTION MESSAGE THROWN HERE"
```

Is there a way to enforce this in Python, with or without libraries?

Suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `assert test_string in {"test_string_1", "test_string_2"}`

Comment: If you can change the signature of this method, then enum can be an option to enforce required values.

Comment: @AzharKhan. That's probably the right answer

Comment: This is a duplicate, I made a recent answer which I think is the best (Same as DeepSpace answered below, I also have a way to enforce it though) https://stackoverflow.com/a/72832981/3936044

Comment: My bad, @Mandera. I had not seen that thread before. DeepSpace's solution should work in my case. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python >= 3.8 supports [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) type, in your case it would be

```
from typing import Literal

def some_func(test_string: Literal["test_string_1", "test_string_2"]):
    ...
```

This, however, will only provide static type analysis and will not raise any run-time exceptions (as any other Python type annotations/ hints won't). For these you will have to use `assert` or explicitly `raise` an exception.