# python - complex boolean search for words in files

Tags: python, search

I have a bunch of files in a folder. Let's assume I convert all into plain text files.

I want to use python to perform searches like this:

```
query = '(word1 and word2) or (word3 and not word4)'
```

the actual logc varies, and multiple words can be used together. Another example:

```
query = '(shiny and glass and "blue car")'
```

Also the words are provided by the users so they are variables.

I want to display the sentences that matched and the filenames.
This really does not need a complex search engine like whoosh or haystack which need to index files with fields.
Also, those tools do not seem to have a boolean query as I explained above.
I've come across `pdfquery` library which does exactly what I want for pdfs, but now I need that for text files and xml files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is the query known to be safe? `eval` would provide an easy out here, but if this is user input it's exceedingly dangerous

Comment: Is that query supposed to be interpreted with old-school search engine-like semantics, where `word` implicitly means "`word` is in the document"?

Comment: The user would type in the words and the semantics (AND,OR,NOT, parentheses).

Comment: @max then you're gonna have to write a lexer. Good luck!

Comment: I don't want to re-invent the wheel. I have nothing against using whoosh or haystack, but after running my eyes through whoosh docs, I could not see any info or example of lexer.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281863/in-python-how-can-i-query-a-list-of-words-to-match-a-certain-query-criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really needed to have such a solution so I made a python package called [toned](https://github.com/kouroshparsa/toned)

I hope it will be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to say this, but *this is not easy.* You're trying to translate unsafe strings into executable code, so you can't take the easy way out and use `eval`. These aren't literals so you can't use `ast.literal_eval` either. You need to write a lexer that recognizes things like `AND`, `NOT`, `OR`, `(`, and `)` and considers them something other than strings. On top you apparently need handle compound booleans, so this becomes quite a bit more difficult than you think it might be.

Your question asks about searching by *sentence*, which is not how Python operates. You'd have to write *another* lexer to get the data by-sentence instead of by-line. You'll need to read heavily into the `io` module to do this effectively. I don't know how to do it off-hand, but essentially you'll be looping while there is data to loop, reading a buffersize each iteration, and yielding when you reach a `"\.(?=\s+)"`

Then you'll have to run your first query lexer results through a set of list comprehensions, each one running across the results of the file lexer.

Comment: And after all of it, you'll wish you'd just used `awk`

Comment: @AdamSmith what if I change the specs to search per line rather than sentence? Is there a solution for that case?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've answered this question too late, but I think the best way to solve complex boolean search expressions is using [this implementation of Pyparsing](https://github.com/xecgr/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/booleansearchparser.py)

As you can see in its description all this cases are included:

```
SAMPLE USAGE:
from booleansearchparser import BooleanSearchParser
bsp = BooleanSearchParser()
text = u"wildcards at the begining of a search term "
exprs= [
    u"*cards and term", #True
    u"wild* and term",  #True
    u"not terms",       #True
    u"terms or begin",  #False
]
for expr in exprs:
    print bsp.match(text,expr)
#non-western samples
text = u"안녕하세요, 당신은 어떠세요?"
exprs= [
    u"*신은 and 어떠세요", #True
    u"not 당신은",       #False
    u"당신 or 당",  #False
]
for expr in exprs:
    print bsp.match(text,expr)
```

It allows wildcard, literal and not searches nested in as many parentheses as you need.