# python string tokenization - custom lexer?

Tags: python, string, tokenize, lexer

I have a string like:

```
<number>xx<->a<T>b<F>c<F>d<F>e<F>f<F>g<T>h<F>i<F>
```

How can I efficiently parse this string so that i.e.

- `xx` has a value of `null`
- `a` has a value of `1`
- `b` has a value of
  `0`

Comment: where do those values come from?

Comment: From a SQL RDBMS where this is part of a comment field ... :(

Comment: Parsing means analysing. You seem to want to change/substitute values. Is that correct? Is <number> meant the be exactly that string or is number meant to be a number?

Comment: Meant to be a `12345:1.23455` type of number. Indeed, Analyze might be a better way to formulate it. In the and (as there are multiple of these records for a single database row) I want to aggregate over the array and sum i.e. all `a`s.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you are expecting? And also how you calculated it. Even reading the other comments I think its a bit unclear what you want.

Comment: FWIW, there is a module called [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) which allows you to build custom lexers https://stackoverflow.com/a/10324600/277267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse that with Regular Expressions. We first remove the initial `<word>`  at the start of the string, if it exists, and then look for pairs of `word<word>`, saving them into key,value pairs in a dictionary using the `codes` dictionary to convert `_`, `F`, `T`,  to `null`, `0`, `1`.

```
import re

s = '<number>xx<->a<T>b<F>c<F>d<F>e<F>f<F>g<T>h<F>i<F>'

m = re.match(r'<(\w*?)>', s)
if m:
    head = m.group(1)
    s = s[m.end():]
    print(head)
else:
    print('No head group')

codes = {'-': 'null', 'F': '0', 'T': '1'}
pat = re.compile(r'(\w*?)<([-\w]*?)>')

out = {k: codes[v] for k, v in pat.findall(s)}
print(out)
```

**output**

```
number
{'xx': 'null', 'a': '1', 'b': '0', 'c': '0', 'd': '0', 'e': '0', 'f': '0', 'g': '1', 'h': '0', 'i': '0'}
```