# Are there any other ways to iterate through the attributes of a custom class, excluding the in-built ones?

Tags: python, class, attributes, python-3.x

Is there another way to iterate through only the attributes of a custom class that are not in-built (e.g. `__dict__`, `__module__`, etc.)? For example, in this code:

```
class Terrain:
    WATER = -1
    GRASS = 0
    HILL = 1
    MOUNTAIN = 2
```

I can iterate through all of these attributes like this:

```
for key, value in Terrain.__dict__.items():
    print("{: <11}".format(key), " --> ", value)
```

which outputs:

```
MOUNTAIN     -->  2
__module__   -->  __main__
WATER        -->  -1
HILL         -->  1
__dict__     -->  <attribute '__dict__' of 'Terrain' objects>
GRASS        -->  0
__weakref__  -->  <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Terrain' objects>
__doc__      -->  None
```

If I just want the integer arguments (a [rudimentary version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937/869912) of an enumerated type), I can use this:

```
for key, value in Terrain.__dict__.items():
    if type(value) is int: # type(value) == int
        print("{: <11}".format(key), " --> ", value)
```

this gives the expected result:

```
MOUNTAIN    -->  2
WATER       -->  -1
HILL        -->  1
GRASS       -->  0
```

Is it possible to iterate through only the non-in-built attributes of a custom class independent of type, e.g. if the attributes are not all integral. Presumably I could expand the conditional to include more types, but I want to know if there are other ways I'm missing.

Comment: You seem to be searching for [flufl.enum](http://packages.python.org/flufl.enum/)

Comment: For simple scripts like this, I always try to use the in-built modules if at all possible, but that module looks intriguing.

Comment: just make your `Terrain` class a subclass of `flufl.enum.Enum` and it's done

Comment: Are you defining any methods or just attributes?  If not defining methods, use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would use:

```
for key, value in Terrain.__dict__.items():
    if not key.startswith("__"):
        print(...)
```

Or I would create an actual enumerated type that did what I wanted.

Comment: Isn't `Terrain.__dict__.items()` equivalent to vars(Terrain).items()?

Comment: For an actual enumerated type, something like [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/67107/) would probably suffice, right? Or is their code that you would use and recommend?

Comment: You should check `key.endswith` too

Comment: Naturally, for instance variables you'd need to use `self` .. so `for key, value in self.__dict__.items():`

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
class GenericClass(object): pass
class_builtins = set(dir(GenericClass))

terrain_attributes = {attr: getattr(Terrain, attr) for attr in dir(Terrain) if attr not in class_builtins}
```

Answer (score 1):

Builtin attributes should start and end with '__' so:

```
[(k,v) for k,v in Terrain.__dict__.items() if not (k.startswith('__')
    and k.endswith('__'))]
```

Some people like to create their own `__attributes__` so this code wouldn't work properly for them. Hey there's a reason why this namespace is *reserved*

You'll also have to check for `__slots__`