# How can I read hexadecimal data with python?

Tags: python, enums, flags

I have this c# app that Im trying to cooperate with a app written in python. The c# app send simple commands to the python app, for instance my c# app is sending the following:

```
        [Flags]
        public enum GameRobotCommands
        {
            reset = 0x0,
            turncenter = 0x1,
            turnright = 0x2,
            turnleft = 0x4,
            standstill = 0x8,
            moveforward = 0x10,
            movebackward = 0x20,
            utility1 = 0x40,
            utility2 = 0x80
        }
```

I'm doing this over TCP and got the TCP up and running, but can I plainly do this in Python to check flags:

```
if (self.data &= 0x2) == 0x2:
    #make the robot turn right code
```

Is there a way in python I can define the same enums that I have in c# (for higher code readability)?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python

Comment: The title is rather misleading - what you are actually searching for are "enums in python", aren't you?

Comment: He is looking for a way to implement bit fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hexadecimal *notation* is just that, a way to write down integer numbers. You can enter `0x80` in your source code, or you can write it down as `128`, it means the same thing to the computer.

Python supports the [same integer literal syntax](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals) as C in that respect; list the same attributes on a class definition and you have the Python equivalent of your enum:

```
class GameRobotCommands(object):
    reset = 0x0
    turncenter = 0x1
    turnright = 0x2
    turnleft = 0x4
    standstill = 0x8
    moveforward = 0x10
    movebackward = 0x20
    utility1 = 0x40
    utility2 = 0x80
```

The C# application is probably sending these integers using the [standard C byte representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29), which you can either interpret using the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html), or, if sent as single bytes, with [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord):

```
>>> ord('\x80')
128
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('B', '\x80')
(128,)
```