# Is it a bad practice to use enums with non-integer types in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

**Suppose I have a class which extends `Enum`, named foo; However, instead of using integers for each item, I use strings**

```
from enum import Enum
class foo (Enum):
    foo = "Hello"
    bar = ", "
    foobar = "world"
    barfoo = "!"
```

**When compiling, the system will throw no errors, and happily treat this class as a normal enum.** As per why anyone would want to do this, it's very useful if you want to link each name to a data structure, like a dict. Take this as an example:

```
from enum import Enum
class foo (Enum):
    foo = {"text" : "Hello", "meaning" : "hello"}
    bar = {"text" : ", ", "meaning" : "comma"}
    foobar = {"text" : "world", "meaning" : "world"}
    barfoo = {"text" : "!", "meaning" : "exclamation"}
```

**Well, maze, why not just use a normal class then?**
Well, its very useful to be able to store this information as an enum, for quick comparison of type. For example, `x = {"name" : "foo", "type" : foo.foo}` can be easily checked for type with `if x[type] is foo.foo`.

**Is this a "bad practice"? By that, I mean:**

1. Is this an intended use of `Enum`?
2. If I took out the `(Enum)` from `class foo (Enum):`, would there be any efficiency difference when comparing?
3. Is there a better way to do what I am wanting to do?

Comment: I would be wary of mutating the values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **Is it a bad practice to use enums with non-integer types in python?**

No, it is not bad practice.

- **Is this an intended use of Enum**

Yes, `Enum` was designed to work with non-integer types.

- **If I took out the (Enum) from class foo (Enum):, would there be any efficiency difference when comparing?**

The non-`Enum` version would probably be faster, but that likely doesn't matter.  (Test for bottle-necks before guessing what needs to be optimized.)

- **Is there a better way to do what I am wanting to do?**

Using mutable types is allowed -- meaning I have taken no steps to prohibit it<sup>1</sup> -- but it's generally not a good idea.  `Enum` members should be constant.  Your example looks like you want to have two extra attributes on each member: `text` and `meaning` -- this is possible on both the stdlib version of `Enum`, and the [`Advanced Enumeration`](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/) version of `Enum`:

```
from aenum import AutoNumberEnum

class Foo(AutoNumberEnum):
    _init_ = 'text meaning'
    foo = "Hello", "hello"
    bar = ", ", "comma"
    foobar = "world", "world"
    barfoo = "!", "exclamation"
```

and in use:

```
>>> Foo.bar
<Foo.bar: 2>

>>> Foo.bar.text
', '

>>> Foo.bar.meaning
'comma'
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19300424/208880) for the stdlib way to accomplish this.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: This guy `enums`

Comment: Woah, the `AutoNumberEnum` is pretty much exactly what I want. Thanks!