# Python Enum with multiple attributes

Tags: python, enums

I have his Enum :

```
class MultiAttr(Enum):
    RED = (1, 10)
    GREEN = (2, 20)
    BLUE = (3, 20)
    def __init__(self, id, val):
        self.id = id
        self.val = val
assert MultiAttr((2, 20)) == MultiAttr.GREEN
```

Assertion passes.

1. Why Pylance in VSCode complains `Argument missing for parameter "val"` ?
2. As the first attribute is the identifer, is there a way to achieve :
   `MultiAttr(2) == MultiAttr.GREEN` ?

Comment: Pylance complains because given the `__init__` you should pass two arguments, `2` and `20`, but you are only passing one argument, a tuple `(2, 20)`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 But `MultiAttr(2, 20)` gives an error. Any thoughts about second question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#when-to-use-new-vs-init), as you want to customize the actual value of the Enum member:

```
from enum import Enum

class MultiAttr(bytes, Enum):
    def __new__(cls, value, otherVal):
        obj = bytes.__new__(cls, [value])
        obj._value_ = value
        obj.otherVal = otherVal
        return obj
    RED = (1, 10)
    GREEN = (2, 20)
    BLUE = (3, 20)


print(MultiAttr(2) == MultiAttr.GREEN)
print(MultiAttr(2).otherVal)
```

Out:

```
True
20
```

Comment: Thanks! One minor issue is that Pylance complains `Member "otherVal" is unknown` on `MultiAttr(2).otherVal`.

Comment: You can define a class attribute with a type `otherVal: int` and that should help type checking @Philippe, see further description here: https://rednafi.com/python/add_attributes_to_enum_members

Comment: For an optionally dynamically created `enum` which works with `pydantic` by name but supports a value of any type refer to the comprehensive answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587442/validate-pydantic-dynamic-float-enum-by-name-with-openapi-description

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to store additional values for enumeration members. [extended-enum](https://github.com/ilichev-andrey/python-extended-enum) - helps to do this

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from extended_enum import BaseExtendedEnumValue, ExtendedEnum, EnumField

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SomeExtendedEnumValue(BaseExtendedEnumValue):
    other_value: int

class MultiAttr(ExtendedEnum):
    RED = EnumField(SomeExtendedEnumValue(value=1, other_value=10))
    GREEN = EnumField(SomeExtendedEnumValue(value=2, other_value=20))
    BLUE = EnumField(SomeExtendedEnumValue(value=3, other_value=20))
```

```
>>> MultiAttr(SomeExtendedEnumValue(2, 20)) == MultiAttr.GREEN
True
>>> MultiAttr.GREEN.value
2
>>> MultiAttr.GREEN.extended_value
SomeExtendedEnumValue(value=2, other_value=20)
>>> MultiAttr.GREEN.extended_value.other_value
20
>>> MultiAttr(SomeExtendedEnumValue(2, 30)) == MultiAttr.GREEN
ValueError: SomeExtendedEnumValue(value=2, other_value=30) is not a valid MultiAttr
```

> If you don't need to compare the `other_value` field, you can use `field(compare=False)`.
> In this case, the comparison will take place on the first field.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SomeExtendedEnumValue(BaseExtendedEnumValue):
    other_value: int = field(compare=False)
```

```
>>> MultiAttr(SomeExtendedEnumValue(2, 30)) == MultiAttr.GREEN
True
```