# How to add attributes to a `enum.StrEnum`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have an `enum.StrEnum`, for which I want to add attributes to the elements.

For example:

```py
class Fruit(enum.StrEnum):
    APPLE = ("Apple", { "color": "red" })
    BANANA = ("Banana", { "color": "yellow" })

>>> str(Fruit.APPLE)
"Apple"

>>> Fruit.APPLE.color
"red"
```

How can I accomplish this? (I'm running Python 3.11.0.)

<sub>This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680080/python-enums-with-attributes), which asks about the original `enum.Enum`.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is much the same as in the other question (but too long to leave in a comment there):

```
from enum import StrEnum

class Fruit(StrEnum):
    #
    def __new__(cls, value, color):
        member = str.__new__(cls, value)
        member._value_ = value
        member.color = color
        return member
    #
    APPLE = "Apple", "red"
    BANANA = "Banana", "yellow"
```

If you really want to use a `dict` for the attributes you can, but you run the risk of forgetting an attribute and then one or more of the members will be missing it.