# Is it possible to pass kwargs to customised python enum

Tags: python, enums, keyword-argument

You can customise an enum so the members have extra attributes.
There are plenty of examples of that to be found.
They all look something like this:

```
class EnumWithAttrs(Enum):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        value = len(cls.__members__) + 1
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    
    GREEN = 'a', 'b'
    BLUE = 'c', 'd'
```

this example is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19300424/6439229

The majority of the examples I found show `__new__` to accept kwargs, but is it actually syntactically possible to pass kwargs to `__new__`?

This gives SyntaxErrors:

```
class EnumWithAttrs(Enum):
    GREEN = 'a', foo='b'
    BLUE = 'c', **{'bar':  'd'}
```

So does this functional syntax:

```
Color = EnumWithAttrs('Color', [('GREEN', 'a', foo='b'), ('BLUE', 'c', **{'bar': 'd'})])
```

Do people put the `**kwargs` in the function def of `__new__` just out of habit, or is there really a way to use them?

EDIT:
I'm not looking for a workaround to using kwargs, like passing a dict as a positional argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to pass keyword args to an enum's `__new__` or `__init__`, although there may be one in the future.

The third-party library `aenum`<sup>1</sup> does allow such arguments using its custom `auto`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
from enum import Enum


class EnumWithAttrs(Enum):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        value = len(cls.__members__) + 1
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj

    def __init__(self, a, attrs):
        self.a = a
        self.attrs = attrs or {}


class AttributeyColor(EnumWithAttrs):
    GREEN = 'a', {'bar': 'b'}
    BLUE = 'c', {'glar': 'blarb'}


print(AttributeyColor.GREEN.attrs)
```

but this feels like abuse of `Enum`s to me...

Comment: Off course you can pass a dict as a positional argument to achieve the same thing as using kwargs, but it doesn't answer the question. I'd like to know if the syntax exists to use kwargs.

Comment: The syntax is then `dict(bar="b", ...)`, there is no free-standing syntax for how keyword arguments are generally passed.